# $L^p$ and $L^q$ space inclusion

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lp-spaces

Let $(X, \mathcal B, m)$ be a measure space.  For $1 \leq p < q \leq \infty$, under what condition is it true that $L^q(X, \mathcal B, m) \subset L^p(X, \mathcal B, m)$ and what is a counterexample in the case the condition is not satisfied?

Comment: Do you want $L^q(X,\mathcal B,m)$ to be any subset of $L^p(X,\mathcal B, m)$, or a *proper* subset? Also did you mean $p \leq q$ or something else in the question?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lp_space#Embeddings

Comment: You should also consider the counting measure on a finite set - what happens in this case?

Comment: The question has been effectively answered by the answers below in the case of finite spaces. For infinite spaces it may be interesting to read: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/55170/is-it-possible-for-a-function-to-be-in-lp-for-only-one-p

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1371017/are-there-relations-between-elements-of-lp-spaces/1371051#1371051

Comment: If your space contains sets of arbitrarily large positive measure then $L^q\not\subset L^p$ if your space contains sets of arbitrarily small positive measure then $L^p \not\subset L^q$..

Answer (score 155):

> **Theorem** Let $X$ be a finite measure space. Then, for any $1\leq p< q\leq +\infty$ $$L^q(X, \mathcal B, m) \subset L^p(X, \mathcal B, m).$$ The proof follows from Hölder inequality. Note that $\frac{1}{p}=\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r}$, with $r>0$. Hence $$\|f\|_{L^p}\leq\text{meas }(X)^{1/r}\|f\|_{L^q}.$$

The case reported on the Wikipedia link of commenter answer follows from this, since of course, if $X$ does not contain sets of arbitrary large measure, $X$ itself can't have an arbitrary large measure.

For the counterexample: $f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$ belongs to $L^2([1,+\infty))$, but clearly it does not belong to $L^1([1,+\infty)).$

**ADD**

I  would like to add other lines to this interesting topic. Namely, I would like to prove what is mentioned in Wikipedia, hope it is correct:

> **Theorem** Suppose $(X,\mathcal B,m)$ is a measure space such that, for any $1\leq p<q\leq +\infty,$ $$L^q(X, \mathcal B, m) \subset L^p(X, \mathcal B, m).$$ Then $X$ doesn't contain sets of arbitrarily large measure.

Indeed it is well defined the embedding operator $G:L^q(X, \mathcal B, m) \to L^p(X, \mathcal B, m)$, and it is bounded.

Indeed the inclusion $L^q(X,\mathcal B,m)\subset L^p(X,\mathcal B,m)$ is continuous. Convergence in $L^p$ and in $L^q$ imply convergence almost everywhere and we can conclude by the closed graph theorem.

By Hölder inequality, $$\|f\|_{L^p}\leq\text{meas }(X)^{1/r}\|f\|_{L^q}.$$ This means $$\|G\|\leq \text{meas}(X)^{1/r}=\text{meas}(X)^{1/p-1/q}.$$ But, considering $f(x)=\chi_X(x)$, one sees that $$\|G\|=\text{meas }(X)^{1/r}<+\infty \Leftrightarrow \text{meas }(X)<+\infty.$$ Now we can proceed by density of the vector space of the simple functions in both $L^p(X,\mathcal B,m)$ and $L^q(X,\mathcal B,m).$

> **Theorem** Let $(X,\mathcal B,m)$ be a measure space. Then $X$ doesn't contain sets of arbitrarily small measure if and only if for any $1\leq p<q\leq +\infty$, one has $$L^p(X, \mathcal B, m) \subset L^q(X, \mathcal B, m).$$

Let us suppose that, for any subset $Y\subseteq X,\quad Y\in\mathcal B$, we have $0<\alpha\leq\text{meas}(Y)$.

It sufficies to prove the statement for simple functions. Pick now $$f(x) =\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\chi_{E_j},$$ where $\{E_j\}_{j=1,\dots,n}$ is a collection of disjoint subsets of $\mathcal B.$ Then $$\|f\|_{L^q} \le \sum_{j=1}^n \|a_j\text{meas}(E_j)\|_{L^q} = \sum_{j=1}^n a_j\text{meas}(E_j)^{1/q}=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\text{meas}(E_j)^{1/q-1/p+1/p}\leq\frac{1}{\alpha^{1/p-1/q}}\|f\|_{L^p}.$$

The first inequality is due to Minkowski inequality.

For the converse of the theorem note that again it is well defined the embedding operator $G:L^p(X,\mathcal B,m)\to L^q(X,\mathcal B,m)$, and the operator is bounded. Now consider that, for any subset $Y\subset X$, $Y\in\mathcal B$, the function $$g_Y(x)=\frac{\chi_Y(x)}{(\text{meas(Y)})^{1/p}}$$ satisfies $$\|g_Y\|_{L^q}= \frac{1}{(\text{meas}(Y))^{1/p-1/q}}. $$
But then, for any $Y\subset X$, $Y\in\mathcal B$, we have $$\frac{1}{(\text{meas}(Y))^{1/p-1/q}}\leq \|G\|,$$ which means $$0<\frac{1}{\|G\|^{1/p-1/q}}\leq \text{meas}(Y).$$ Hence the result is proved.

Comment: A slightly better counterexample is given by $f_p(x)=x^{-1/p}$; this function belongs to $L^q(1,\infty)\setminus L^p(1,\infty)$ provided $q>p$.

Comment: In the second theorem (the first after the add), how do you show that the embedding $G\colon L^q\to L^p$ is bounded?

Comment: What's is a definition of meas(X)?

Comment: I'm sure you made a mistake in the proof of the last theorem. Now suppose $f$ is a simple function, i.e. $f(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n a_j\chi_{E_j}$, where $E_j$ are disjoint, the $L^q$ norm of $f$ should be $$\|f\|_{L^q}=\left(\sum_{j=1}^n a_j^q\mu(E_j)\right)^{1/q}$$.

Comment: @juaninf Most probably, $\operatorname{meas}X=m(X)$ is the $m$-measure of $X$.

Comment: When you say sets of "arbitrarily small measure" I'm assuming this is disregarding measure $0$ sets?

Comment: But how can you apply Holder inequality if measure of $X$ isn't finite?!

Comment: hi @uforoboa how one can show that if p<q then it is not true that $||f||_p<||f||_q$ in the measure space $(N,P(N),\mu)$ where $\mu$ id the counting measure?

Comment: I think your proof of the first theorem after the ADD, as stated, is incorrect. You wrote in the proof: 
"By Hölder inequality, $$\|f\|_{L^p}\leq\text{meas }(X)^{1/r}\|f\|_{L^q}."$$ But, by applying Hölder inequality in this way, you are (implicitly) assuming that $\chi_X \in L^q$, which means $X$ has finite measure. However, the fact that $X$ has finite measure is **exactly** what you want to prove.

Answer (score 76):

In Rudin's book *Real an complex analysis*, we can find the following result, shown by Alfonso Villani:

> Let $(X,\mathcal B,m)$ be a $\sigma$-finite measure space, where $m$ is a non-negative measure. Then the following conditions are equivalent:
>
> 1. We have $L^p(X,\mathcal B,m)\supset L^q(X,\mathcal B,m)$ for some $p,q$ with $1\leqslant p<q<\infty$.
> 2. $m(X)<\infty$.
> 3. We have $L^p(X,\mathcal B,m)\supset L^q(X,\mathcal B,m)$ for all $p,q$ with $1\leqslant p<q<\infty$.

We only have to show that $1.\Rightarrow 2.$ and $2.\Rightarrow 3.$ since $3.\Rightarrow 1.$ is obvious.

$1.\Rightarrow 2.$: the inclusion $L^q(X,\mathcal B,m)\subset L^p(X,\mathcal B,m)$ is continuous. Indeed, let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence in $L^q$ which converges to $f$ for the $L^q$ norm, and to $g$ for the $L^p$ norm. We extract a subsequence which converges almost everywhere to $f$ and $g$ (first extract a subsequence $\{f_{n_j}\}$ which converges to $f$ almost surely; this sequence still converges to $g$ for the $L^p$ norm; now extract from this sequence a subsequence which converges to $g$ almost surely), hence $f=g$, and by the closed graph theorem we get the conclusion since both $L^p$ and $L^q$ are Banach spaces.

Therefore, we can find $C>0$ such that $\lVert f\rVert_p\leqslant C\lVert f\rVert_q$. Since 
 $X$ can be written as an increasing union of finite measure sets $A_n$, we get that 
 $m(A_n)^{\frac 1p}\leqslant Cm(A_n)^{\frac 1q}$, hence $m(A_n)^{\frac{q-p}
 {pq}}\leqslant C$ and since $p\neq q$: $m(A_n)\leqslant C^{\frac{pq}{p-q}}$. Now we 
 take the limit $n\to\infty$ to get $m(X)\leqslant C^{\frac{pq}{p-q}}$.

$2.\Rightarrow 3.$: let $1\leqslant p<q<\infty$ and $f\in L^q$. We put $E_n:=
 \left\{x\in X: \frac 1{n+1}\leqslant |f(x)|\lt\frac 1n\right\}$ for $n\in\mathbb N^*$. 
 The sets $\{E_n\}$ are pairwise disjoint and by $2.$ we get $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}
 m(E_n)<\infty$. The function $f$ is integrable because 
 \begin{align*}
 \int_X |f|^pdm &=\int_{\{|f|\geq 1\}}|f|^pdm+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\int
 _{E_n}|f|^pdm\\\
 &\leqslant\int_X |f|^qdm+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac 1{n^p}m(E_n)\\\
 &\leqslant \int_X |f|^qdm+\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}m(E_n)<\infty.
 \end{align*}
 Now we look at the case $q=+\infty$. If $m(E)<\infty$, since for each $f\in L^q$ we 
 can find $C_f$ such that  $|f|\leqslant C_f$ almost everywhere, we can see $f\in L^p$ for 
 all $p$. Conversely, if $L^{\infty}\subset L^p$ for a finite $p$, then the function 
 $f=1$ is in $L^p$ and we should have $m(E)<\infty$.

Comment: I don't see how you can just pick one subsequence in step 1 that converges to bot $f$ and $g$. It seems you can you just pick one for $f$ (or $g$), using Theorem 4.9 in Breviz, but how can you pick one that converges to both?

Comment: I have added details.

Comment: Shouldn't the $p,q$ verify $1\leqslant p<q \leq\infty$ at all steps instead of $1\leqslant p<q<\infty$? Bounded (essentially) function $f$ in a finite measure set implies $f \in L^p$ $\forall p  \geq 1$. i.e. $L^{\infty} \subset L^p$.

Answer (score 47):

There is a easy way to show that. Suppose that $p<q$ and X a space measure finite. Take any $f\in L^q$. Then, the q-norm is finite. In this way,
$$\int_X|f|^p = \int_{f(x)<1}|f|^p + \int_{f\geq1}|f|^p \leq\int1+\int_{f\geq1}|f|^q\leq\mu(X)+||f||_q^q<\infty$$
A counter example just take $$f(x)=\frac{1}{x}$$ for $x\in(0,\infty)$ and Lebesgue measure. Then $f$ belongs to $L^2$ (integral is 1) but not $L^1$.

Comment: You mean $x\in (1,\infty)$ here don't you?

Comment: How did you get that $\int 1 \leq \mu(X)?$

Comment: @Luiz ^^^^^^^^^^

Comment: @user161518 can you explain how they got $\int 1 \leq \mu(X)$

Comment: is it because its the integral split into two cases so the first part need bee less than the total measure of the space ?

Answer (score 3):

This is to show that the restriction $1\leq p<q\leq\infty$ in the OP is not needed, and that the following result holds:

> ***Theorem A:*** Suppose $(\Omega,\mathscr{F},\mu)$ is a $\sigma$-finite measure space. There exists $p,q$ with $0<p<q\leq\infty$  such that $L_q(\mu)\subset L_p(\mu)$ iff $\mu(X)<\infty$.

Sufficiency follows directly from Hölder's inequality. In fact, if $0<p<q\leq\infty$,
$$\int_X|f|^p\,d\mu\leq \|f\|^p_q\big(\mu(X)\big)^{1-\tfrac{p}{q}}$$

Necessity can be shown using the simple and elegant argument described in Davide's [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66045/121671). First some general observations about $L_p(\mu)$ spaces with $0<p<\infty$.
To ease notation, we define $\|f\|_p=\Big(\int_X|f|^p\,d\mu\Big)^{1/p}$.

1. The function $d_p:L_p(\mu)\times L_p(\mu)\rightarrow[0,\infty)$ given by
   $$d_p(f, g)=\Big(\int_X|f-g|^p\,d\mu\Big)^{\min(1,1/p)}=\|f-g\|_p^{\min(p,1)}$$
   defines a complete translation invariant metric on $L_p(\mu)$, and so, $(L_p(\mu),d_p)$ is an $F$-space. (Of course when $p\geq1$, $L_p(\mu)$ is a Banach space with norm $\|f\|_p=d_p(0,f)$; for $0<p<1$, see this [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4174997/121671)).
2. The sets $B_p(0;r)=\{f\in L_p(\mu): d_p(0,f)<r\}$ form a local basis of neighborhoods for $(L_p(\mu),d_p)$.
3. For any $r>0$, $B_p(0;r)=r^{\max(1,1/p)}B_p(0;1)$.

Now recall the general versions of the Closed Graph Theorem in the setting of $F$-spaces.

> Theorem: Suppose $X$ and $Y$ are $F$-spaces. If $\Lambda:X\rightarrow Y$ is linear and its graph $G=\{(x,\Lambda x):x\in X\}$ is closed in $X\times Y$, then $\Lambda$ is continuous (and thus bounded since $X$ and $Y$ are metrizable).

This can be sen for example in Rudin, W., *Functional Analysis, McGraw-Hill*, second edition, 1991, pp. 51

---

Now we have all the ingredients to modify Davide's proof to the  present setting. Suppose $L_q(\mu)\subset L_p(\mu)$ for some $0<p<q<\infty$. Consider the inclusion map $\iota: L_q(\mu)\rightarrow L_p(\mu)$. The continuity of $\iota$ follows from the Closed Graph Theorem just as explained by Davide:
Suppose $(f_n:n \in\mathbb{N})\subset L_q(\mu)$ is a sequence which converges in $L_q(\mu)$ to some $f\in L_q(\mu)$, and which also converges in $L_p(\mu)$ to some $g\in L_p(\mu)$. Along a subsequence $f_{n'}$,  $|f-f_{n'}|^q\rightarrow0$ $\mu$-a.s. Then, along a subsequence $f_{n''}$ of $f_{n'}$,
$|f_{n''}-g|^p\rightarrow0$ $\mu$-a.s. It then follows that $f=g$ $\mu$-a.s. and so $\iota$ is bounded.

The key to extend the statement of the OP to the present setting is to understand how bounded sets in general $L_p(\mu)$ spaces look like.

> ***Claim:***  For any $0<r\leq \infty$, $E\subset L_r(\mu)$ is bounded iff
> $$\sup\left\{f\in E: \|f\|_r\right\}<\infty$$

Proof: By definition (see Rudin, cit. op.)  $E$ is bounded iff for any open neighborhood $U$ of $0$ in $L_p(\mu)$ there is $s>0$ such that
$E\subset sU=\{sf: f\in U\}$. Notice that
$$\|\lambda f\|^{\min(r,1)}_r=d_r(0,\lambda f)=\lambda^{\min(r,1)}\,d_r(0,f)=\lambda^{\min(r,1)}\|f\|^{\min(1,r)}_r$$
The conclusion of the claim follows immediately from observations (2) and (3), and  by taking $U=B_r(0;1)$.

In particular, by observation (3) we have that any ball $\overline{B}_p(0;r)=\{f\in L_p(\mu):d_p(0,f)\leq r\}$ is bounded in $L_p(\mu)$.

By the continuity of $\iota$, $\overline{B}_q(0;1)$ is bounded in $L_p(\mu)$ since $\overline{B}_q(0;1)$ is bounded in $L_q(\mu)$. This means that
$$c:=\sup_{f\in \overline{B}_q(0;1)}\|f\|_p<\infty$$

Notice that for any $f\in L_q(\mu)\setminus\{0\}$, $\frac{1}{\|f\|_q}f\in \overline{B}_q(0;1)$. Hence
$$\|f\|_p\leq c\|f\|_q,\qquad f\in L_q(\mu)$$
Let $(A_n:n\in\mathbb{N})\subset\mathcal{F}$ such that $A_m\nearrow \Omega$. Then
$$\big(\mu(A_n)\big)^{\tfrac{1}{p}-\tfrac{1}{q}}\leq c$$
whence we conclude that $\mu(X)\leq c^{\tfrac{pq}{q-p}}<\infty$.

Finally the case $0<p<q=\infty$ is simpler for if
$L_\infty(\mu)\subset L_p(\mu)$, then as $f\equiv1\in L_\infty(\mu)$,
$$\|f\|_p=\big(m(X)\big)^{1/p}<\infty$$

Answer (score 2):

I'd like to provide a proof of a result mentioned in @uforoboa's answer, in which the proof seems questionable.

> **Theorem** Let $1 \leq p < q < \infty$, and $(X, \it{M}, \mu)$ be a measure space. If $\exists c > 0$ such that for all $A \in \it{M}$ either $\mu(A) = 0$ or $\mu(A) \geq c$, then $L^p(X, \mu) \subset L^q(X, \mu)$.

Proof: Let $f$ be a function in $L^p(X, \mu)$. By Tchebyshev's inequality,$$\mu(E_t) \leq (\frac{\|f\|_p}{t})^t$$ where $E_t = \{x:|f(x)| > t\}$.
Note when $t > \|f\|_p$, $\:(\frac{\|f\|_p}{t})^t \to 0$ as $t \to \infty$.
That is to say, $\exists T > \|f\|_p$ such that, $$\mu(E_T) < (\frac{\|f\|_p}{T})^T < c$$ Hence $$\mu(E_T) = 0$$
Then $$\|f\|_q^q = \int |f|^q = \int_{E_T}|f|^q + \int_{E^c_T}|f|^q = \int_{E_T^c}|f|^q$$
Since $|f| \leq T$ on $E^c_T$ and $p < q$,
$$\|f\|_q^q = \int_{E_T^c}|f|^q = \int_{E_T^c}|f|^p|f|^{q-p} \leq T^{q-p}\int_{E_T^c}|f|^p \leq T^{q-p}\|f\|_p^p < \infty$$
By we which we conclude $f \in L^q(X, \mu)$ as desired.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively one can take into account this proposition.

> $\textbf{Proposition. }$Let $(X, \mathcal{A}, \mu)$ a finite measure space. Let $f$ be $\mathcal{A}$-measurable function and let $E_{n} = \{x \in X: (n - 1) \leq \lvert f (x) \rvert < n\}$. Then $f \in L^{p}(X)$ if and only if $$\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n^{p} \mu(E_{n}) < + \infty.$$

Using this proposition, we have that for $1 \leq q < p$, if $f \in L^{p}(X)$ then
$$
\sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n^{q} \mu(E_{n}) \leq \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} n^{p} \mu(E_{n}) < + \infty.
$$
Hence $f \in L^{q}(X)$. So we have the inclusion
$$
L_{p}(X) \subset L_{q}(X).
$$

Answer (score 1):

I would like to provide a proof restricted to probability space.
Recall that Jensen's inequality states that if $X$ is a random variable and $c$ is a convex function:
$$ \mathbb{E}(c(x)) \geq c(\mathbb{E}(x)) $$

Then let $1 \leq p < q < \infty$, and set $c(x):=x^{\frac{q}{p}}$, since $\frac{q}{p}$ is greater than 1, then $c$ is convex, so for any $X \in L^q(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$
$$||x||_p = (\mathbb{E}(|x|^p))^{\frac{1}{p}} = (c(\mathbb{E}(|x|^p)))^{\frac{1}{q}} \leq (\mathbb{E}(c(|x|^p)))^{\frac{1}{q}} = (\mathbb{E}(|x|^q))^{\frac{1}{q}} = ||x||_q$$
Then $||x||_p$ is well defined, this implies $X \in L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P})$, so
$$ L^q(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}) \subseteq L^p(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mathbb{P}) $$
However, I don't think this proof works for general finite measure space since Jensen's inequality only works for probability space. See the related answer

> [Does Jensen's inequality still hold in general finite measure space?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3763605/does-jensens-inequality-still-hold-in-general-finite-measure-space#:%7E:text=No.,%CE%BC%20is%20a%20probability%20measure.https://)