# some facts about $L_p$ space

Tags: normed-spaces

I was wondering relations of $L_p$ spaces..

Let $E$ be a measurable set. If $E$ is of finite measure, then $L_p(E) \subset L_q(E)$, $1 \le p \le q \le \infty$.

However, does it still hold if $E$ is infinite?

Comment: It may hold, (when we take a countable set with counting measure) or not ($\Bbb R$ with Lebesgue measure). See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/lp-and-lq-space-inclusion/66045#66045 for information about inclusion of $L^p$ spaces.

Comment: I think the inclusion should be in the other direction.

Comment: Your inclusion goes the wrong way. In finite measure spaces for $p \le q$ you have $L^p \supseteq L^q$. If you have a measure with no sets of arbitrarily small positive measure (like the counting measure) then your inequality is true. In general measure spaces none of these inclusions hold in general.

Comment: Thank you guys for your answers.