# Does $X_n \stackrel{Prob}{\longrightarrow} X$, $X \in L^2$ imply $X_n \stackrel{L^2}{\longrightarrow} X$?

Tags: probability-theory

Let $X_n$, $n\in \mathbb{N}$ be a sequence of random variables which converges in probability to $X$, i.e. $X_n \stackrel{Prob}{\longrightarrow} X$. Furthermore it is known that $X \in L^2$. Does this imply $X_n \stackrel{L^2}{\longrightarrow} X$?

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/lp-and-lq-space-inclusion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. For example, consider $X_n=\sqrt n\cdot\chi_{[0,1/n]}$ in $L_2([0,1])$. $(X_n)$ converges to the zero function in probability and $\Vert X_n\Vert_{L_2}=1$ for each $n$.

Comment: Thanks for the counterexample. I know uniform integrability is sufficient to conclude. Do you know any other assumption such that the L^2 convergence holds?

Comment: @Harry If you have  pointwise convergence and if everything is in $L_2$, then  $\Vert X_n \Vert_{L_2}\rightarrow\Vert X\Vert_{L_2} $ implies $\Vert X_n-X\Vert_{L_2}\rightarrow0$.

Answer (score 1):

Take a sequence $X_n$ that converges in probability to zero (the zero function) but such that no $X_n$ is square integrable. The zero function is in $L_2$ but the sequence does not converge in $L_2$ to zero.

Comment: Thanks! I know uniform integrability is sufficient to conclude. Do you know some other assumption such that the L^2 convergence holds?