# Examples of measures that induce certain inclusions in the Lp spaces.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

I apologize for the terribly worded title, but I didn't know how else to title this questions (which comes from Rudin's Real & Complex Analysis chapter 3 questions).

The question says:

> For some measures, the relation $r<s$ implies $L^r(\mu)\subset L^s(\mu)$; for others, the inclusion is reversed; and there are some for which $L^r(\mu)$ does not contain $L^s(\mu)$ if $r\neq s$. Give examples of these situations, and find conditions on $\mu$ under which these situations will occur.

I am having an extremely difficult time grasping any/everything having to do with measures and Lp spaces, so this question is mind-crippling. I don't even know where/how to begin thinking about such a question. Any input/help/criticism is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Here are some cases to begin with: What about $L^p((0,1))$ (with Lebesgue measure)? What about $\ell^p(\Bbb{N}) = L^p(\mu)$, where $\mu$ is counting measure on $\Bbb{N}$? Hint: In the first case, Hoelder's inequality is useful.

Comment: Related : [$L^p$ and $L^q$ space inclusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029)

Answer (score 4):

1) By Holder's Inequality it is immediate to show that $L^p(\Omega) \subset L^q(\Omega)$ for $p \ge q$ if you consider the usual Lebesgue measure on a set of *finite* measure.

2) Note that $\sum x^p$ converges if $\sum x^q$ converges provided $p \ge q$. This means that $\ell^q(\mathbb{N}) \subset \ell^p(\mathbb{N})$, which we can rewrite as $L^q(\mathbb{N},\#) \subset L^p(\mathbb{N},\#)$, where $\#$ is the counting measure.

3) Consider the Lebssgue measure on an set of *infinite* measure. This is an example where there's no inclusion of the $L^p$ spaces, but it is trickier to prove.

I hope this helps! :)