# How to apply Holder inequality to prove the following?

Tags: malliavin-calculus

In the book "Malliavin Calculus and related topics", the author states that $||F||_{k,p}=((E(|F|^p)+\sum_{n=1}^k E(||D^n F||^p_{H^k}))^{\frac{1}{p}}$ has monotonicity property, i.e. $||F||_{k,p}\leq ||F||_{j,q}$ when $k\leq j$ and $p\leq q$ if $F$ is smooth random variable. To complete the proof, I need to know how to prove for the case when $p<q$ and $k=j$. Someone suggests to use Holder inequality, but in general, $q$ and $p$ are not conjugate. How to apply Holder inequality to prove it? If Holder inequality cannot be used to prove it, how to arrive the conclusion then?

Comment: What does the notation inside the second expectation stand for? Is $D^n$ the $n^{th}$ derivative with respect to something? What is $H^k$ in the subscript? Last point: Why are you taking the expectation of what looks like a norm, which is another expectation?

Comment: $H$ is a real separable Hilbert space. You can treat that $D^n$ to be the $n^{th}$ derivative. For example, $F=f(W(h_1)...W(h_n))$, then $DF=\sum \partial_i f(W(h_1)...W(h_n))h_i$. Note that W(h_{.}) is isonormal Gaussian process, $h$ lie in $H$.

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. prove first that $\|F\|_{k,p} \leq \|F\|_{j,p}$, i.e. with the same $p$ but $k \leq j$.
2. Use the fact that you are in a probability space and invoke [the standard inclusion for $L^p$ spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951418/examples-of-measures-that-induce-certain-inclusions-in-the-lp-spaces).