# $1 \le p < q < \infty$ implies $L^q \subset L^p$

Tags: lp-spaces

Suppose $1 \le p < q < \infty$ and $(X,\mu)$ is a Lebesgue measure space. Also suppose $X$ is of finite measure. Prove that $L^q \subset L^p$.

First, we use Holder's inequality and find $$\int_X |f|^p \, dx \le \left( \int_X |f|^q \, dx \right)^{\frac pq} \left(\int_X \, dx \right)^{1-\frac pq}$$
which reduces to $$\|f\|_p \le \|f\|_q \mu(X)^{\frac 1p - \frac 1q} = C\|f\|_q$$
Does this give me the conclusion $L^q \subset L^p$?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Examples of measures that induce certain inclusions in the Lp spaces.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/951418/examples-of-measures-that-induce-certain-inclusions-in-the-lp-spaces)

Comment: $||f||_1$ should be $||f||_p$. Otherwise you are right.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Elements of $L^q$ are precisely those classes of measurable functions with $\| f \| _q < \infty$. Now if you have such an $f \in  L^q$, due to the inequality you have found you will also have $\| f \| _p \le C \| f \| _q < \infty$, so $f \in L^p$, therefore $L^q \subset L^p$.

Comment: but you need $\mu(X)$ to be finite. Don't you?

Comment: @zap: It is already assumed in the statement of the problem, read it carefully: *"Also, suppose $X$ is of finite measure"*. You might also want to delete your answer.

Comment: you're right. I didn't read this part. Or maybe was edited