# consider the normed linear spaces $(\mathcal C[0,1], ||.|| _i)$.what can you conclude about the correspoding open unit balls?

Tags: functional-analysis

consider the normed linear spaces $$(\mathcal C[0,1], ||.|| _1), \;(\mathcal C[0,1], ||.|| _2),\;(\mathcal C[0,1], ||.|| _3)\ldots, (\mathcal C[0,1], ||.|| _p)$$ and $(\mathcal C[0,1], ||.|| _\infty)$. Then what can you conclude about the correspoding open unit balls?

**My work**

$||f||_1=\int_0^1 |f| d\mu\leq1$ (because it is in unit ball)

And so, I can give large height triangle whose area is simply $<1$. So, the unit ball with respect to $||.||_1$ need not be the subset of the unit ball w.r.to $||.||_\infty$ What happens for the remaining cases? If I use $U_i$ for the unit ball w.r.to $||.||_i$, can I conclude that

$$U_1\supset U_2\supset\ldots \supset U_\infty$$

Comment: No $\|f\|_1 = \int_0^1 |f|d\mu$. You can't forget the absolute value inside the integral, or else $\|f\|_1=0$ is possible for $f(x)=x-\frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: yes.. you are right.. thanks for the note. I have corrected.@ThomasAndrews

Comment: Yes, you can conclude that. Do you know Hölders inequality?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/lp-and-lq-space-inclusion