# Proof of $L_q(\Omega) \subset L_p(\Omega)$ when $1\leq p \leq q \leq \infty$

Tags: lebesgue-integral

I need to prove that  $L_q(\Omega) \subset L_p(\Omega)$ when $1\leq p \leq q \leq \infty$ when $\Omega$ is bounded. The hint given is that I should use Hölders inequality. How do I start my proof using this inequality?

Comment: Suppose $f\in L^q(\Omega)$. You want to see that $\int_{\Omega} \lvert f\rvert^p\,d\mu$ is finite. Any idea how Hölder's inequality can give an upper bound on that integral?

Comment: already been addressed: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/lp-and-lq-space-inclusion