# $L_p(\mu)\subseteq L_q(\mu)$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lp-spaces

Given a measure space $(\Omega,\mathfrak A,\mu)$ and $1≤q≤p$, how can I show that $$L_p(\mu)\subseteq L_q(\mu)$$ if the measure $\mu$ is finite, that means $\mu(\Omega)<\infty$?

Comment: Hint/Solution: Hölder inequality

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1729675/if-f-in-l2-pi-pi-then-f-in-l1-pi-pi-and-f-l1-leq-sqr/1729734#1729734).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$L^p$ and $L^q$ space inclusion](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/lp-and-lq-space-inclusion)

Answer (score 2):

Hint:

$$|f(x)|^q \le \max(|f(x)|^p,1)$$