# Continuous injection and density in $l^p$ spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, continuity, banach-spaces

If $r\le s$ then $l^r\subseteq l^s$. How can I prove there is a continuous injection $l^r\hookrightarrow l^s$? The suggestion was to use the fact that $\Vert x\Vert_r\le\Vert x\Vert_s$. Also how can I prove that $l^1$ is dense in $l^2$?

Thank you!!

Comment: What is $l_r\,\,?$

Comment: The collection of elements s.t. the countable sum of its absolute values to the power r is finite

Comment: Don't you mean the $r$th power of the absolute values?

Comment: Yes, I edited it as soon as I re-read it, but thanks. Do you have any insights to add to Leo's answers?

Answer (score 0):

Consider the map
$$\phi: l_r \to l_s : f \mapsto f.$$
This map is well defined, that is 
$$f \in l_r \Rightarrow f \in l_s;$$ 
to see this just observe the following inequalities for $f \in l_r$:
$$||f||_s < || f ||_r < \infty.$$
This shows that $f \in l_s$.
Clearly this map is injective. Suppose $\phi(f) = \phi(g)$, then 
$f = \phi(f) = \phi(g)  = g$, which proves injectivity.

For continuity: just use the epsilon definition of continuity in metric spaces for the map $\phi$.

For density:  Pick any $\epsilon$ and any $f \in l_2$. Construct a function  $g \in l_1$ such that $||f - g||_2 < \epsilon$. 
Since you picked everything arbitrarily you've proven that $l_1$ is dense in $l_2$.

HINT FOR DENSITY: Take any $f = (a_i)_{i \in \mathbb{N} }\in l_2$. There exists some $N \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\sum_{n= N}^\infty a_n^2 < \epsilon$. Can you use this information to construct some $g \in l_1$ such that $||f-g||_2< \epsilon$? So $||f ||_2^2= \sum_{n=0}^{N-1}a_n^2 + \sum_{n= N}^\infty a_n^2$.

Here is a link worth looking at: 
[$L^p$ and $L^q$ space inclusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/lp-and-lq-space-inclusion)

It is a bit different but I think it will help you.

Comment: I'm not sure on the injection part. Injection means that the map $\phi$ you defined exists, how can I prove this? Is it suficient to prove that the norm of x in $l_s$ is not bigger than the norm in $l_r$?
As for the density part, can I pick y=x / ∥x∥ (where x is a sequence of $x_n$)? This way I prove that if y and x are in $l_1$ then y is also in $l_2$.
Thank you very much for your help!

Comment: I've included some edits that show injectivity. Try to do continuity yourself. As for density, write down the formula for || f ||_2. For some $f$ can you write $f $ as the sum of two elements $g$ and $e$ one of which is an element $l_1$ and the second of which has $||.||_2$ norm smaller than $\epsilon$?

Comment: Thanks. My idea would be to take $g_i$ = $f_i$$^2$ for all i, but then ||f-g||$_2$ would be zero? This isn't possible because the inclusion is not proper... Can you give me another hint? Or flat out the solution, althoufg thinking about it is actually useful.

Comment: You have a pretty clear hint for density now :)

Comment: @user1952009 I was hoping that he/she would figure that out by himself ;)

Comment: Do I? ;) I can't think of anything better than this and this seems wrong because the difference is exactly zero and so $l_1$=$l_2$. I have now thought this might not be true, I have only found an example of equality, this doesn't mean there do not exsist functions which are in $l_2$ but not in $l_1$. But I did say for all f... so this doesn't seem totally right. Oh dear, help, please!

Oh I have a question: in the first answer you wrote for every $f$ in $l_2$, in the comments you said for some $f$. I would say it has to  be for every $f$, correct?

Comment: Oh no, I missed the comment! ;)  (Not French, but a lady here, btw)
So this popped into my mind. What if I add an $\epsilon$ to $g$? Definitely not sure about this though, it seems pretty useless really

Comment: Here are a couple more hints: Do you you think $f := \sum_{n=0}^Na_n$ is in $l_1$? What happens when you subtract it from an element in $g \in l_2$  for which it holds that $f(i)=g(i)$ for $0 \leq i \leq N$?

Comment: It is, if the $a_n$s are not $\infty$, and surely if the  $a_n$ are "my"  $d_i$s ). If I subtract it, the element is still in $l_2$ and it's a tail of a converging series so its limit is zero?!

Comment: if you subtract everything but the tail, the tail itself has ||.||_2 norm less then $\epsilon$, which concludes the proof.  (This of course only holds if you pick N large enough, take another look at the hint ;) )

Comment: But why would I need to do that? Where is the mistake with the $g_i$ = $f_i$$^2$idea? (the  $g_i$ are the elements of the sequence) Is there a problem if the difference is exactly zero?
Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm sorry, I have one last question.
I was discussing this with a friend and he told me to use the properties of ortonormal spaces.
If $V$ = $l_1$ and $V_o_r_t_o_g_o_n_a_l$ = $V^o$= (closure of $V^o$) = {0}, then the closure of $l_1$ = $l_2$. 
By proving <$x$,$y$>$_2$ = 0 for all $y$ in $l_1$, $x$ = 0. Is this correct? Thank you for your help!!