# Set inclusion involving the set of locally integrable functions

Tags: lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $0 <p < q < \infty$. Why exactly does the inclusion $L_{\mathrm{loc}}^q(\mathbb{R}^n) \subseteq L_{\mathrm{loc}}^p(\mathbb{R}^n)$ hold?

For clarification:

[image: def]

Comment: Holder's inequality.

Comment: This might be similar http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/lp-and-lq-space-inclusion

Comment: Thanks a lot. I totally forgot the regularity of the Lebesgue measure.