# Are $\ell^p$ spaces a special case of $L^p$ spaces?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

My professor said that $\ell^p$ spaces are $L^p$ spaces with a discrete measure. But how can that be true if that the inclusion of the spaces is in different directions in the two cases? In the first case, $\ell^p \subset \ell^q$ if $p < q$, while $L^q \subset L^q$ if $p < q$!

Comment: Both the inclusions you mentioned are true only if some conditions are met. Check this link : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/lp-and-lq-space-inclusion

Comment: You write $L^p$, but what is the domain of the functions in that space?

Comment: We only have $L^q\subset L^p$ for $q<p$ if the measure is finite. This is not the case for $\ell^p$.

Comment: To elaborate Mariano's comment: The spaces $L^p[0,1]$ and $L^p(\mathbb{R})$ are different.

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez Thanks, your comment made me realize I was being totally imprecise in my reasoning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The proof of the inclusion $L^q(\mu) \subset L^p(\mu)$ for $p<q$ you saw probably assumed that $\mu$ is a *finite* measure.  This inclusion does not hold in general (consider $\mu$ the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$).

What your professor was hinting towards was the fact that $\ell^p=L^p(\mu)$, with $\mu$ the measure on $\mathbb{N}$ (with $\sigma$-algebra the power set of $\mathbb{N}$, hence the term *discrete measure*) given by
$$\mu(A)=|A|,$$
where $|A|$ denotes the number of elements of $A$.