# $L^p(X)$ and $L^q(X)$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces

Suppose $p \leq q$. Does there exist a space $X$ such that $L^p(X) \subset L^q(X)$ or $L^q(X) \subset L^p(X)$? What about a space $X$ such that $L^p(X) - L^q(X)$ nonempty, $L^q(X) - L^p(X)$ nonempty?

EDIT: Here is what I have so far:

(a) For $L^p(X) \subsetneq L^q(X)$, take $X = [0,1]$ which holds since $[0,1]$ has finite measure.

(b) For $L^q(X) \backslash L^p(X)$, take $x \in (1, \infty)$ and the function $1/x$. This function is in $L^2(1,\infty)$ but not $L^1(1, \infty)$.

(c) $L^p(X)\backslash L^q(X)$ - I still have nothing.

(d) $L^q(X) \subsetneq L^p(X)$ I still have nothing. I want to consider a set $X$ which does not contain a subset of arbitrarily small measure?

Comment: Many of the answers you seek can be found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/lp-and-lq-space-inclusion).
Here are a few points.
If $X$ is a single point, then these function spaces are all equal to $\mathbb{R}$.
If $X$ has finite measure, then $L^q(X) \subset L^p(X)$.
If $X=[1,\infty)$, then $f(x)=x^{-1/p}$ is in $L^q(X)$ but not $L^p(X)$.

Comment: You want $p<q,$ right?

Comment: For all cases, you can use $X = \mathbb R$ equipped with the Lebesgue measure. For $p \ne q$ you neither have $L^p(X) \subset L^q(X)$ nor $L^q(X) \subset L^p(X)$.

Comment: @angryavian What about $L^p \subset L^q$? And for $L^q \subset L^p$, simply take $X = [0,1]$? And lastly, what about show that $L^p \backslash L^q$ can be nonempty?

Comment: @zhw. I have made an update.

Comment: @angryavian I have made an update.

Comment: @gerw I have made an update.