# Proving that the operator $G: L_p[0,1] \to L_q[0,1]; G(x)=x$ is linear, well defined and continuous. And find it's norm.

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lp-spaces

Proving that the operator $G: L_p[0,1] \to L_q[0,1]; G(x)=x$ is linear, well defined and continuous. ($p\geq q$)

Linearity is trivial.
The well-defined part, with continuity and norm isn't. (for me)

I have to prove:
$$\|G(x)\|_{L_q[a,b]}<+\infty ; x \in L_p[a,b]$$
or $$\int_{a}^{b}|x(t)|^qdt<\infty$$ having that $\int_{a}^{b}|x(t)|^pdt<\infty$.
We have done Holder equality, but I dont think I can use that directly seeing as $1/p + 1/q = 1$ doesn't necessarily have to be true.

Comment: Hölder is the way. To transform $\lvert x(t)\rvert^q$ into $\lvert x(t)\rvert^p$, you need the exponent $r = \frac{p}{q}$.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [$L^p$ and $L^q$ space inclusion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/lp-and-lq-space-inclusion)