# Lebesgue integrable nonexample

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral

Does $f\in \mathrm L^p$ imply that $f$ is Lebesgue integrable? If not can anyone give me an example?

I don't have any conditions on my domain or the function.

Comment: $1/x\in L^2(1,\infty)$ but not in $L^1$.

Comment: @yanko But it is in $L^1$

Comment: No it is not because the sum $\sum \frac{1}{n}$ converge to infinity

Comment: What is the domain of the functions? If it is some compact interval, then yes, $f\in L^p$ implies $f$ is Lebesgue integrable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a domain $\Omega$ with  finite measure $L^q(\Omega)$ is contained in $L^p(\Omega)$ for $1\leq p\leq q \leq \infty$. But on unbounded domains there need not be a strict relation like this as shown by the comment by yanko.

You can find some details in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/lp-and-lq-space-inclusion.)

Comment: So the sufficient condition is that the domain should be bounded. thanks a lot