# Find a sequence Cauchy in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, but not Cauchy in $L^q(\mathbb{R})$ for $p\not = q$

Tags: real-analysis

For all $p,\,q\in[1,\infty)$, $p \not = q$, find a sequence of Lebesgue measurable function $f_n:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ so that $f_n\in \cap_{r\in[1,\infty)}L^r(\mathbb{R})$, and $(f_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ is a Cauchy sequence in $L^p(\mathbb{R})$, but not a Cauchy sequence in $L^q(\mathbb{R})$.

I was able to this problem given $p < q$, using result in [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/lp-and-lq-space-inclusion), but I cannot find one that true on $p \not = q$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: try some multiples of indicator functions of intervals.  Depending on whether $p < q$ or the reverse, make the graphs tall and skinny or short and fat.

Comment: I can find one by using multiples of indicator functions, but that only works for $p<q$ or reverse. But I want to find one that is true whenever $p\not = q$.

Comment: You can combine one for $q < p$ and one for $q > p$ to get a sequence that is Cauchy in $L^p$ but not in $L^q$ for any $q \ne p$.