# Functions which are $L^p$ but not $L^{p+1}$ for arbitrary $p$.

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, lp-spaces

Fixing an arbitrary $p$, can a function always be found which is $L^p$ but not $L^{p+1}$ or $L^{p-1}$ on $\mathbb{R}_{\geq0}$?

More generally, given a pair $\big(a,b\big)\in\mathbb{Z}_{\geq1}^2$, can a function $f$ always be found which is $L^p$ iff $p\in\big(a,b\big)$ or iff $p\in\big[a,b\big]$?

Comment: Maybe this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/lp-and-lq-space-inclusion could answer your question into the negative.

Comment: What is the domain of $L^p$? $\mathbb R$?

Comment: @PrudiiArca Yes, I updated the question.

Comment: In general $\{ p : f \in L^p \}$ for any particular $f$ is an interval, including the possibility of an empty set, a singleton, an open interval, a closed interval, and a half-open interval. This can be shown by developing an interpolation inequality for $\| f \|_{L^r}$ in terms of $\| f \|_{L^p}$ and $\| f \|_{L^q}$ when $p<r<q$.

Comment: (Cont.) And in the setting of $[0,\infty)$ with the Lebesgue measure, nothing more can be said: all of those possibilities can be attained. On a finite measure space you can say more, and on a measure space such that $\{ m(A) : m(A)>0 \}$ is bounded away from zero you can say more. The details for this are in Tito's link. But $[0,\infty)$ with the Lebesgue measure is neither of those.