# What is denoted by an element + a space (i.e. $f+L^2$)

Tags: definition

What does the definition of a space + an element mean, for example $f+L^2$.

Is this the same as the direct sum $\{f\}+L^2$, e.g.
$$\{f+g|g\in L^2\}$$

Comment: What's the context? I'm inclined to say yes it's that set (not sure why you call it a direct sum since $\{f\}$ is not a vector space) without any context.

Comment: @OsamaGhani The context is functional analysis and pdes.

Comment: @Tony The broad context is kind of clear from writing $L^2$, but what is a specific instance, where you found that notion confusing? eg something like „let $f+L^2$ be an element in $L^3(X)/L^2(X)$ (assuming $X$ is wellbehaved https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/66029/lp-and-lq-space-inclusion). Please consider adding this type of context **to your question** as it makes it easier for others to understand your problem and answer the question in your terms.