# Question about the $L^p$ being complete.

Tags: real-analysis, banach-spaces, lp-spaces

I was wondering if $L^p$ is complete whenever we have $0<p<1$ when we define the metric $d(f,g) = \int |f-g|^p$? I think the answer would be yes, but I cannot come up with a proof. It seems to me that it would be in the same spirit of proving the case for $p \geq 1$ but I am unsure.

Comment: Did you follow the proof of the $p \ge 1$ case? If so, at what point were you unable to proceed?

Comment: @Ian $d(0,1)+d(1,2)=2$ and $d(0,2)=2^p<2$ because $p<1$.

Comment: @UmbertoP. I am unsure how to go about the argument. When I try to mirror steps used in $p \geq 1$ I run into difficulties because $d$ is only a metric.

Comment: @Krull -- Can you prove that $d(x,y)=|x-y|^p$ is a complete metric on $(-\infty,\infty)$ for $0<p<1$?

Comment: @Ian Thank you for your comment. Isn't $d(0,2) \leq d(0,1)+d(1,2)$ what we want? As you said $2^p < 2$, so that example does not work.

Comment: @uniquesolution: I have not tried proving this, but will this help with the overall proof?

Comment: Gah I'm forgetting what the property that breaks is. There is an important property that goes awry for $p<1$. Maybe it was that the balls aren't convex?

Comment: @Krull -- I believe it will. Doing mathematics means doing, not asking what do.

Comment: @Ian the balls aren't convex, and the metric is not a norm (because it is not homogeneous).

Comment: @WolfgangKrull if you already tried to mirror the steps, you should include these steps in your question and point out exactly where it goes wrong.
 Otherwise people have to redo your work again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This problem may have already several answers. Here is yet another one. Some details (How Fatou's is used and so on are left for the OP).

---

For $0<p<1$, $a^p+b^p\geq (a+b)^p$ for all $a,b\geq0$. From this, it follows that $$d(f, g)=\int|f-g|^p\leq \int(|f-h|+|h-g|)^p\leq d(f, h) + d(h, g)$$ Completeness follows a similar proof than that of $L_p$, $p\geq1$.
Suppose $\{f_n: n\in\mathbb{N}\}$ is Cauchy in $L_p$ and choose subsequence so that $d(f_n,f_{n_k})<2^{-k}$ for all $n\geq n_k$. Define $$\begin{align}G_K&=|f_{n_1}|+\sum^K_{j=1}|f_{n_{j+1}}-f_{n_j}|\\
G&=|f_{n_1}|+\sum^\infty_{j=1}|f_{n_{j+1}}-f_{n_j}|\end{align}$$
Then
$$\begin{align}
\int G^p_K&=\int(|f_{n_1}|+\sum^K_{j=1}|f_{n_{j+1}}-f_{n_j}|)^p\leq \int|f_{h_1}|^p+\sum^n_{j=1}\int|f_{n_{j+1}}-f_{n_j}|^p\\
&\leq d(0,f_{n_1})+\sum^\infty_{j=1}2^j<\infty
\end{align}$$
From that and monotone convergence, $G$ converges a.s. Hence the series $g= f_{n_1}+\sum^\infty_{j=1}(f_{n_{j+1}}-f_{n_j})$ converges absolutely  almost surely and so, $f_{n_j}$ converges almost surely to say $f$. The rest is and application of Fatou's to check that $f\in L_p$ and that $d(f_{n_j},f)\xrightarrow{j\rightarrow\infty}0$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think the first line you wrote should read $(a+b)^p \leq a^p + b^p$ no?

Comment: @WolfgangKrull: That's right. I just corrected the direction of the inequality. Thanks!