# $\mathcal{L}^{p}(\mu) \backslash \mathcal{L}^{p'}(\mu) \neq \emptyset$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

Let $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $1 \leq p' < p \leq \infty$ and $\mu$ be $\sigma$-finite but not finite. I am trying to prove that $\mathcal{L}^{p}(\mu) \backslash \mathcal{L}^{p'}(\mu) \neq \emptyset$. Hence I am trying to find an $f \in \mathcal{L}^{p}(\mu)$ such that $f \not \in \mathcal{L}^{p'}(\mu)$. Since $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, I thought I would start by decomposing $\Omega = \bigcup_{k = 1}^\infty A_k$, where $A_k \in \mathcal{F}$ and $\mu (A_k) < \infty$ for all $k \in \mathbb{N}$. Then I thought about setting $f = \sum_{k = 1}^\infty a_k 1_{A_k}$ for suitably defined $a_k$ such that the function has finite $p$-norm but infinite $p'$-norm. However, I am having troubles finding such $a_k$. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Note: $\mathcal{L}^p (\mu)$ is the set of real valued measurable functions with finite $p$-norm.

Comment: In my question $p > 1$, so this example does not really help me here. Also, my measure space is given.

Comment: Again, same comments apply.

Comment: See DavideGiraudo's [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/66045/121671). That should answer your question.

Comment: Where exactly does he provide an example of an $f$ that is in $\mathcal{L}^p(\mu)$ but not in $\mathcal{L}^{p'}(\mu)$? I don't see it. Note that my measure space is assumed to be $\sigma$-finite, but *not* finite.

Comment: Ah, I didn't even think to negate the statement of the theorem. That works, thanks a lot!

Comment: I just realize that there is no need to restrict $p$ and $p'$ to $[0,\infty)$. In fact, we can consider any $0<p<p'<\infty$. I posted this observation [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4542475/121671)

Comment: Will have a read, thanks