# A measurable function non integrable on any interval

Tags: measure-theory, integration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [examples of measurable functions on $\mathbb{R}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24413/examples-of-measurable-functions-on-mathbbr)

Is there a measurable function $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R} ^{+}$ such that $\int_{[a,b]}g dx=\infty$  $\forall a\neq b \in\mathbb{R}$ .

Comment: Are we assuming Lebesgue measure?

Comment: yes I will edit it

Comment: Clearly g cannot be continuous...

Comment: Yes otherwise it will have a maximum by the extreme value theorem

Comment: See: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/24413