# A function with few Lebesgue point?

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-measure

It is well know that if $f:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{C}$ is integrable, i.e. $\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}|f|dm<\infty$, then almost every point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a Lebesgue point of $f$, i.e.
$$\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{m(B(x,r))}\int_{B(x,r)}|f-f(x)|dm=0,$$
for almost all $x\in\mathbb{R}^n$.

What if $f$ is not integrable? Is there an example of a function $f$ that has no Lebesgue point on a set of positive measure? Can we find $f$ such that almost all $x$ is not a Lebesgue point? Or perhaps there is even a function that has no Lebesgue point at all!

Comment: See the following post: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/24413/is-there-a-function-with-infinite-integral-on-every-interval