# ‎Is ‎$‎\int_{-‎\infty‎}^{+\infty}f(x)dx‎$ ‎convergent (as Riemann integrable), where ‎$‎f$ is a Riemann integrable ‎$PDF$‎?‎

Tags: probability, integration, probability-theory, probability-distributions

‎Let‎  ‎$‎‎f:‎\mathbb{R}\to‎\mathbb{R}‎$  be a  Riemann integrable probability density function on every closed ‎interval ‎of ‎‎$‎‎‎\mathbb{R}‎$‎. As I explained in my previous question   ([Does there exist any probability density function ‎$‎f:‎\mathbb{R}\to‎\mathbb{R}‎$ ‎which is not Riemann integrable?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3047260/does-there-exist-any-probability-density-function-f-mathbbr-to-mathbbr)) ,  Now I have 2 questions as follows:

Question‎(1)‎‎‎‎ ‎Is ‎‎$‎‎\int_{-‎\infty‎}^{+\infty}f(x)dx=‎‎\int_{-‎\infty‎}^{0}f(x)dx+‎‎\int_{0‎}^{+\infty}f(x)dx‎‎$ ‎convergent?‎

Question‎‎‎(2) Is ‎$‎‎\lim_{x\to +‎\infty‎}f(x)=0$ true?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/829927/general-condition-that-riemann-and-lebesgue-integrals-are-the-same

Answer (score 2):

For question 1) the answer is YES and it follows from the fact that the Riemann integral of a Riemann integrable fucntion coincides with the Lebesgue integral. 
For question 2) the answer  is NO: let $f(x)=c\sum nI_{(n,n+\frac 1 {n^{3}})}$ where $c$ is chosen such that $f$ integrates to $1$.

Comment: 1 and 2 you mean that Question‎(1) and Question‎(2) or the both are related Q2?

Comment: @soodehMehboodi I hope the answer is clear now.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy, thanks a lot.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy, would you tell me, which conditions make question 2) be true?

Comment: @soodehMehboodi If a density function is uniformly continuous on $\mathbb R$ we can show that $f(x) \to 0$ as $x \to \infty$.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy, Excuse me , I have a general question, If $F$ is the CDF function of the PDF function $f$ then Is $F^\prime=f$ always true? would you help me? thanks.

Comment: @soodehMehboodi $F'=f$ almost everywhere for any PDF.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy, Thank you.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy, Would you tell me that, why it must be uniformly continuous? Can continuous work alone?

Comment: Draw triangles with vertices $(n-\frac 1 {n^{2}},0), (n+\frac 1 {n{2}},0), (n,1)$ (n>2) and combine these to get the graph of a continuous function $f$. A constant multiple of this function is a density function which is continuous but its vales at $3,4,\cdots$ do not tend to $0$.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy, Firstly thanks a lot for your leading, Now my question is: " for a probability density function ($f$), does there exist a cumulative distribution  function ($F$)"?

Comment: @soodehMehboodi Of course! $F(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x} f(t)\, dt$ defines the cumulative distribution function.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy, Hi again, Excuse me for my several questions, I have a question about your previous comment. if $f$ has a continuous derivative then,  is question 2  true? I mean that does continuous derivative work instead of uniformly continuous?

Comment: @soodehMehboodi No. You an construct infinitely differentiable density functions that do not tend to $0$.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy, Thanks for your advice, also quickly responding.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy, hello, I know that if $f$ is continuous then $F^\prime=f$ is  always true.  Now I have a question : if $f$ is monotonic, does the equality always true or a.e?

Comment: @soodehMehboodi Yes. Lebesgue's Theorem says that if $f$ is integrable on finite intervals and $F(x)=F(a)+\int_{a}^{x}f(t)\, dt$ then $F'(x)=f(x)$ almost everywhere.

Comment: @ Kavi Rama Murthy, you mean that monotonic can not work same as continuous, and the equality is true a,e. not always.