# Does there exist a subset $S$ in $[0,1]$ such that for all interval, $S$ and its complement in the interval has the same Lebesgue masure?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I would want to see a strengthening or a disproof of a result from an exercise from Rudin's *Real and Complex Analysis*, that is asked before at here [Construct a Borel set on R such that it intersect every open interval with non-zero non-"full" measure](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/961745/construct-a-borel-set-on-r-such-that-it-intersect-every-open-interval-with-non-z) and here [Construction of a Borel set with positive but not full measure in each interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57317/construction-of-a-borel-set-with-positive-but-not-full-measure-in-each-interval) and possibly elsewhere.

Does there exists a subset $S\subseteq [0,1]$, such that for all intervals $(a,b)\subseteq [0,1]$, the subset and its complement are measurable and has the same positive Lebesgue measure in $(a,b)$, that is, $\mu((a,b)\cap S)=\mu((a,b)\setminus S)=\dfrac{b-a}{2}$?
Thanks.

Comment: I guess you mean $\mu$ is the Lebesgue measure and $$\mu((a,b)\color{red}{\cap} S)=\frac{b-a}{2}$$

Comment: See also [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4451617/473276). LDT works but it's a bit overkill - [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/103306/473276) is a simpler reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming $\mu$ stands for the Lebesgue measure, the existence of such a set $S$ would imply that

$$\mathbf{1}_{S}(x)=\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\mu(S\cap[0,x])=\frac{1}{2}\quad\text{a.e.}$$

by [Lebesgue's differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem), which is of course a contradiction.