# Must probability density be continuous?

Tags: probability

From other materials that I've read, the probability density of a continuous random variable must itself be continuous. Is this correct? If it is, I don't understand why that would be so, why can't the probability change abruptly?

Comment: If I recall correctly, there is a restriction to at most countable discontinuities.

Comment: At least one discontinuity is common in densities of *practical* importance.

Comment: @DrewChristianson: Perhaps you are thinking of probability *distribution* functions.  A density function can even be everywhere discontinuous.

Comment: "Continuous" distribution means the cdf (cumulative distribution function) is continuous.  This does not mean the density is continuous, or even that a density exists.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Take $f(x) = 2x$, $0\le x \le 1$, and 0 otherwise.  This is a density function which is not continuous.

Comment: I thought so. Thanks!

Answer (score 12):

Michael Chernick asks for an example of a probability distribution with a density that is everywhere discontinuous.

As discussed in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57317/construction-of-a-borel-set-with-positive-but-not-full-measure-in-each-interval), there exists a measurable set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that for every interval $I$, we have $0 < m(A \cap I) < m(I)$, and moreover $m(A) < \infty$.  Then $f(x) = \frac{1}{m(A)} 1_A(x)$ is a nonnegative measurable function with $\int_\mathbb{R} f(x)\,dx = 1$, so it can be taken as the density of a continuous probability distribution.  $f$ is nowhere continuous because every interval contains points of $A$ and $A^C$.  Moreover, any function $g$ with $f=g$ a.e. is also nowhere continuous.

Comment: (+1) More generally, a construction similar to the following should work: Let $f$ be a probability density function continuous on $\mathbb R$. Take $g = f \cdot 1_{(\mathbb R \setminus \mathbb Q)}$.

Comment: @cardinal: This works, of course, but just noting that the function in my answer is in some sense "worse", in view of my last sentence.  For your function, you can modify it on a null set (which doesn't really change it as a density function) and get something everywhere continuous.  For mine, no matter how much you modify it on null sets, it remains nowhere continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Although valid I don't think the triangular density given by ncmathsadist is a good example.  The U[0.1] density is discontinuous too because of the abrupt rise at x=0 and drop at x=1.But both these densities are continuous within their domain.  I think a better example  would be one with a discontinuity in its domain.
Consider the density f(x)=2x for 0<=x<=1/2

and f(x)=(5-2x)/16 for 1/2

Certainly a density can have many such discontinuities.  But can anyone give an example of a true probability distribution with a density that is everywhere discontinuous?

Comment: In some sense, *all* probability distributions that are absolutely continuous have (a *version* of) a density that is everywhere discontinuous on the closure of its support.

Comment: @cardinal: Could you please supply a reference or post an answer to explicate your assertion? Thank you.

Answer (score -1):

No, need not be. However, the cumulative distribution function (CDF), is always continuous (mayn't be differentiable though) for a continuous random variable.
For discrete random variables, CDF is discontinuous.

[image: Taken from MIT6_041F10 Lecture slides]

Comment: First, CDF is not cumulative density function. CDF is cumulative distribution function. Second, question is asking about probability density functions (PDF's) not about CDF's.

Comment: I thought a CDF was only required to be right continuous?