# Differentiable parametrization of the Weierstrass function

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, parametrization, almost-everywhere

I understand that the [Weierstrass function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) is an example of a function that is continuous everywhere but differentiable nowhere. I was thinking if it is possible to "make the Weierstrass function differentiable" somehow. One approach on this was already discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/828115/modifications-of-weierstrasss-continuous-nowhere-differentiable-functions).

My approach is the following: The Weierstrass function (let us call it $w$) can be represented as the set $$W := \{ (x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \mid w(x)=y \}$$

I am wondering if there is a differentiable *parametrization* $p:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ of $W$, in the sense that

- $W = p(\mathbb{R}) := \{ p(t) \mid t \in \mathbb{R} \}$
- $p$ is injective
- $p$ is differentiable (almost everywhere would be fine)

**Is there such a parametrization?**

---

My guess is no, because based on a differentiable parametrization, we could probably compute the derivative of $w$ itself. However, I have not found out how to do this yet...

Answer (score 0):

Of course we'd need to have $p'(t)=0$ almost everywhere.

In fact the answer is yes, at least for almost-everywhere differentiability. The "Cantor function" $x:[0,1]\to[0,1]$ is a continuous non-decreasing surjective function with the following property: There exists an *open* set $E\subset[0,1]$ with $m(E)=1$ such that $x$ is constant on each connected component of $E$. So if we let $p(t)=(x(t), w(x(t)))$ then $p$ is constant on each connected component of $E$, hence $p'=0$ almost everywhere.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Unfortunately, I forgot to specify that my parametrization should also be injective (otherwise, it would be a strange parametrization). I think in that case, the Cantor function cannot be applied directly?