# On Compact and Measurable Sets with Positive Length

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, compactness

Greetings fellow Mathematics enthusiasts! The following two-part problem is giving me trouble, and I was hoping someone could help me solve it. It is coming from Terrence Tao's *Introduction to Measure Theory* textbook. The free online/pdf version is linked at the end of this post.

**i).** Give an example of a compact set $K \subset \mathbb{R}$ of positive measure such that $m(K \cap I) < |I|$ for every interval $I$ of positive length.

I am given a hint to first construct an open dense subset of $[0,1]$ of measure strictly less than 1.

Here is my approach:

Since $K$ is compact, then it is contained in a countable union of open sets $\bigcup_ {n=1}^{\infty}B_n$. We want this set to be a dense subset of $[0,1]$ with measure strictly less than 1. So consider the set $E= \mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]$. Then we have that $E=\mathbb{Q}\cap[0,1]=\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}[q_k,q_k]$ for some enumeration of the rationals. This implies that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}0=0$. Since $K\subset E$, then $m(K\cap I) \leq m(E\cap I) < |I|$.

**ii)**. Give an example of a measurable set $E\subset \mathbb{R}$ such that $0<m(E\cap I)<|I|$ for every interval $I$ of positive length.

For this part, I am given the hint to consider the compliment of the set $K$ above. If so, then won't $K$ be a countable intersection of closed sets?

As always, any help is greatly appreciated, thanks in advance.

Link to the free textbook:
http://terrytao.files.wordpress.com/2011/01/measure-book1.pdf

Comment: This could be helpful: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57317/construction-of-a-borel-set-with-positive-but-not-full-measure-in-each-interval

Comment: Thank you very much for the reference! It was indeed very helpful.