# Set with positive Lebesgue measure but no interval

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, examples-counterexamples

This question tortures me for a while:
if a set $E$ has positive [Lebesgue measure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_measure), does it necessarily contain an interval?
I would be truly grateful for help.

Comment: No, think about the Smith–Volterra–Cantor set.

Comment: Thank you. I will look it up.

Comment: The answerer has voted to close this question... Why vote to reopen?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The irrational numbers are such an example.

Comment: +1. Small comment: it's possible to come away from this problem, and facts like regularity, with the impression that a positive measure set must *almost* contain an interval: that is, for all $E$ measurable with positive measure, there is a nontrivial interval $I$ such that $I\subseteq E\cup Z$ for some measure-zero set $Z$. However, this is false: see http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57317/construction-of-a-borel-set-with-positive-but-not-full-measure-in-each-interval.

Comment: @NoahSchweber Good point; that's a good example of how [Littlewood's three principles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood's_three_principles_of_real_analysis) can sometimes be a bit misleading.

Comment: I feel totally mislead. With the "fat" Cantor set, for example, they say that it is the boundary of the set which brings that positive measure, not the set itself. But since the set is closed, is not the boundary included into the set?

Comment: @Marina Yes, that set is closed and is equal to its own boundary.

Comment: Things like this make me believe that the real numbers are not continuous.

Comment: @Marina : ​ Bear in mind that the fat Cantor set's interior is empty, so everything in it is in its boundary. ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: @user296602 , can you  explain how the irrationals (as a subset in $R$) have a finite positive Lebesgue measure but don't contain any inerval (not singletons)?