# Constructing a fat Cantor Set with certain property

Tags: real-analysis, geometric-topology

Let $\mu $ be Lebesgue outer measure, does there exist a certain fat Cantor $ C $ such that $\mu (C) > 0$ and  for every $ x  \in C $ the ratio $\frac {\mu (C\cap [x ,x+1/n])}{\mu (C^c\cap [x , x+1/n])} \to \infty$ as $ n\to\infty $

If such set exists we may answer the interesting question 
 [When does $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x+\frac{1}{n})=f(x)$ a.e. fail](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612281/when-does-lim-n-to-inftyfx-frac1n-fx-a-e-fail)?

Comment: What do you conclude from the Lebesgue density theorem?  Perhaps: for almost every point of $C$, $$\lim\frac{\mu(C \cap [x,x+1/n])}{1/n} \to 1\qquad\text{and}\qquad\lim\frac{\mu(C^c \cap [x,x+1/n])}{1/n} \to 0$$

Comment: @GEdgar thanks for noticing , the limit in my question should be $\to \infty $  not $0$, i edited that

Comment: So the question is: can  this 'almost everywhere" thing hold everywhere in $C$?  Answer: no.  At the left-hand end of one of the removed open intervals, your limit is $0$.

Comment: @GEdgar Have you looked at the original question, the one linked to above? It seems like such an obvious question I can't believe we don't all know the answer - so far all I can prove is a counterexample must be complicated...