# Measure of a Cantor like set

Tags: solution-verification, lebesgue-measure

It is a well known fact how to construct Cantor sets of any measure $\alpha\in[0,1)$ by removing middle third intervals. Here is a different kind of procedure of constructing a nowhere dense set of positive length I found in Bogachev's Measure theory, Volume 1:

- Starting with $I=[0,1]$, for any $n\in\mathbb{N} (=\{1,2,\ldots\})$, divide $I$ in $2^n$ subintervals of equal length.
- For each of the $2^n$ subintervals $I_{n,j}$ remove the open subinterval of length $2^{-2^{n+1}}$ whose right endpoint is that of $I_{n,j}$.
- Let $A_n$ be the union of the remaining closed subintervals, and define
  $$ A=\bigcap_nA_n$$
  The set $A$ has positive Lebesgue measure.

**Edit:** What I am trying to check is whether I got the correct estimate for the measure of $|A_n|$:
$$\begin{align*}
\alpha_n&:=|A_n|=4\cdot 2^{-2^{n+1}}\prod^n_{j=1}(2^{2^j}-1)\\
&=4\cdot 2^{-2^{n+1}}2^{2^1+2^2+\ldots +2^n}\prod^n_{j=1}(1-2^{-2^j})\\
&=\prod^n_{j=1}(1-2^{-2^j})
\end{align*}$$

The limit of this product is indeed positive, as the explanations by David Ulrich and Oliver Diaz show. If anyone could help me corroborate the expression I got for $\alpha_n$ I would appreciate it.

Comment: All you actually want is to show that $\lim\alpha_n>0$, right? A basic fact about infinite products: If $0<t_n<1$ and $\sum t_n<\infty$ then $\prod(1-t_n)>0$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DavidC.Ullrich. My concern is more about making sure that the product is indeed positive.

Comment: "open subinterval of length $2^{n+1}$": should be $2^{-(n+1)}$?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich: thanks! I had forgotten about those facts about infinite products.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is more a comment than a solution expanding on David C. Ulrich's

1. Recall that a sequence $q_n=\prod^n_{k=1}(1+a_k)$, with $a_n\neq-1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ converges to $p\neq0$ iff for any $\varepsilon>0$ there is $N_\varepsilon>0$ such that
   $$\Big|\prod^k_{j=1}(1+a_{n+k}) -1\Big|<\varepsilon,\qquad n\geq N, \, k\in\mathbb{N}$$
   See for example, T. Apostol's Mathematical Analysis, p.p. 207.
2. Also, recall that a product $q_n=\prod^n_{k=1}(1+a_n)$ is said to converge absolutely (again $a_n\neq-1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$) iff $Q_n=\prod^n_{k=1}(1+|a_k|)$ converges. Based on the criteria in (1), it is not difficult to check that if $q_n$ converges absolutely, then $p=\lim_nq_n$ exists and $p\neq0$.
3. Finally, recall that $q_n=\prod^n_{k=1}(1+a_n)$  converges absolutely (again $a_n\neq-1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$) absolutely iff $\sum_n|a_n|<\infty$. This follows from the inequality
   $$ \sum^n_{k=1}|a_k|\leq \prod^n_{k=1}(1+|a_k|)\leq \exp\Big({\sum^n_{k=1}|a_n|}\Big)$$

I did not checked whether the expression you give is indeed the length of the intervals that make up $A_n$, but the expression you gave does converge (absolutely as in (2)) to something positive on account that (1) $2^{-2^k}\neq1$ for all $k\in\mathbb{N}$ and (2) $\sum^\infty_{k=1}\frac{1}{2^{2^k}}<\infty$.

I don't know if there is a known expression for $\prod^\infty_{n=1}(1-2^{-2^n})$ though.