# When does $f_n = f(x + 1/n)$, uniformly converge to $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, proof-explanation, uniform-convergence, sequence-of-function

[This source (p.15)](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-100a-real-analysis-fall-2020/mit18_100af20_hw_final.pdf) claims that a sequence of functions $ f_n : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R},$ with $f_n = f(x + 1/n)$, converges to $f$ uniformly on $\mathbb{R}$.

Unless some more conditions are placed on $f$, this would seem untrue to me.  For example, let $f(x) = 0$ if $x=0$ and $1$ otherwise.  Then, for any $n, f(0) = 0,$ while $f_n(0) = f(1/n) = 1.$

If $f$ is uniformly continuous, the claim is true, as for all $x$, for all $\epsilon > 0$, $n > 1/\delta \implies |f_n(x) - f(x)| < \epsilon$.

If $f$ is merely continuous, I believe it converges, but not necessarily uniformly.

*Note: This question is related to, but distinct from, similar discussions (e.g. [When does $\lim_{n\to\infty}f(x+\frac{1}{n})=f(x)$ a.e. fail](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2612281/when-does-lim-n-to-inftyfx-frac1n-fx-a-e-fail) ), as I'm asking about a claim in a [specific source](https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/18-100a-real-analysis-fall-2020/mit18_100af20_hw_final.pdf); and because this discussion concerns elementary real analysis* without *measure theory.*

Comment: I think you're correct. As for the case where $f$ is merely continuous,  you can consider the example $f(x)=x^2$.

Comment: The source you link to says says $f$ is differentiable and $|f'(x)| \leq L$ for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$. This assumption implies $f$ is $L$-Lipschitz on $\mathbb{R}$ but you are correct that the claim is true if $f$ is uniformly continuous.