# Finding $f$ s.t. the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=f (x − a_n )$ is not a.e. convergent to $f$

Tags: measure-theory, measurable-functions, pointwise-convergence

The following is an exercise from [Bruckner's Real Analysis](http://onlinebooks.library.upenn.edu/webbin/book/lookupname?key=Bruckner%2C%20Andrew%20M.):

> Let $a_n$ be any sequence of positive numbers converging to zero. If $f$ is continuous, then certainly $f (x − a_n)$ converges to $f (x)$. Find a bounded measurable function on $[0, 1]$ such that the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=f (x − a_n )$ is not a.e. convergent to f [Hint: Take the characteristic function of a Cantor set of positive measure.]

I don't understand how "$f_n(x)=f (x − a_n )$ is not a.e. convergent to f" can happen at all : $f (x − a_n )$ are 'moving' to become $f(x)$ as $n \to \infty$ and we only have a solution for not a.e. convergent to f when we consider **any** different $f$ that is not a.e. limit of $f_n$? So what is the use of fat Cantor sets here?

**Added** - There should be an easy solution within the scope of Bruckner's book because when an exercise is hard and even still is at the book's level, it is always mentioned in a parenthesis "This is hard", but no notice for this exercise is.

Comment: It is notable that this exercise appears in the section on Egorov's theorem.

Comment: @OliverDiaz, it's possible and if so, that would be the only exercise of that kind up to first 5 chapters. I could find one of the authors' emails and I sent this link of OP for him today, hopefully I'll get a response!

Comment: @L.G. Interesting enough, one of the answers to the [OP](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2612281/121671)  also used maximal functions, as I did. You will learn those kinds of things later in your analysis course. Although the link I am sending you is for $a_n=\frac1n$, the method of maximal functions can handle the more general case in your problem. To me, however, the interesting answer is that of Alex Ravsky ( I send you the link already)... Finally, just to say I hope you test went smoothly :)

Comment: @L.G.  By now, I am almost convinced that a simple solution that follows the hint is either very tricky or probably not so simple. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2616850/121671)  is something to pick your interest a little further. Alexande gives an answer in the spirit fo the hint, but relies in a careful study of translates of compact sets. I also have a solution for this special case $a_n=\frac1n$  which appears as an exercise in Bogachev's measure theory, but I just realize that the OP to the link I'm sending has already nice solutions. I'll post mine only if you are interested.

Comment: @OliverDiaz, Thank you for both comments. I will look at the OP you sent in a few days (I have another exam: Functional An.) - And my exam went not so well, but the main reason was that the instructor is a jerk being ridiculously pedantic not my answers!

Comment: @SeanEberhard, our TA also thinking that the theorem should be useful, since the function takes only two values, 0 and 1.

Answer (score 3):

I ignore whether a simple answer (as the hint might suggest) to this OP exists (I have tried the suggestion myself to no avail).  I hope there is such simple a solution, and that someone comes up with one along the lines of the hint. Relaying on heavier machinery however,  I present a solution to the OP.

1. First, I show  that  for any given sequence $a_n\searrow0$, there is $f\in L_1([0,1],m)$ such that
   $$\begin{align}
   m(\{x:f_n(x-a_n)\stackrel{n}{\nrightarrow}f(x)\})>0\tag{0}\label{zero}
   \end{align}
   $$
2. From such a function $f$,  one can then construct a measurable bounded function $\phi$ in $[0,1]$ satisfying \eqref{zero}. Indeed, let $B=\{x:f_n\stackrel{n}{\nrightarrow}f\}$. As $f\in L_1$, there is $n_0\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $m(|f|>n_0)<\frac12 m(B)$. Then $m(B\cap\{|f|\leq n_0\})>0$ and the function $\phi:=|f|\mathbb{1}_{B\cap\{|f|\leq n_0\}}$ would do the job.

It is worth mentioning that there is a weaker (simple) version of the problem (see below) and that a related [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1920408/convergence-in-norm-but-not-almost-everywhere-of-f-t-n-f-cdot-t-n-to-f/4042931#4042931) has been discussed in MSE before. In fact, @Ramiro's initial solution to this OP (still visible to some) solves that related problem.

---

**Weaker version of the problem:** there is a bounded measurable function $f$ such that the $\tau_hf(x)=f(x-h)$ does not converge to $f(x)$ as $h\rightarrow0$  for any point $x$ in a set of positive Lebesgue measure.

To prove this, we follow the hint in the OP, and consider any fat Cantor set $F$ in $[0,1]$. Since $F$ is perfect and nowhere dense, for any $x\in F$ there are sequences $\{p_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset F$ and $\{q_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset [0,1]\setminus F$ such that $\lim_n p_n=x=\lim q_n$. Let $h_n=x-p_n$ and $k_n=x-q_n$. Then $\lim_nh_n=0=\lim_nk_n$ and
$$\begin{align}
\lim_n f(x-h_n)&=\lim_n f(p_n)=1=f(x)\\
\lim_n f(x-k_n)&=\lim_n f(q_n)=0\neq f(x)
\end{align}
$$
This complete the proof of the weak case.

---

**Observation:** The weak version as such does not provide a solution to the OP since the sequence of translations $\tau_{h_n}f$ and $\tau_{k_n}f$ depend on the point $x\in F$.

---

**$L_1$-version of the problem:** It will be convenient to consider the problem on $\mathbb{T}$ (the circle of radius one centered at $0$, or $\mathbb{R}\mod 1$)  with sum $\mod 1$, and arc-length measure (Lebesgue's measure on $\mathbb{T}$). Following a suggestion by [Anthony Quas](https://mathoverflow.net/a/45250/78591) in his answer to a question related to the [Ergodic theorem](https://mathoverflow.net/q/28997/78591), one may look instead for existence of integrable functions (or locally integrable functions) $f\in L_1(\mathbb{R},m)$ such that $\tau_{a_n}f$ does not converge to $f$ almost surely. In this case, one may use Maximal functions (similar to the classical techniques of Hardy-Littlewood's, Wiener's,  Doobs, for example) to analyze point wise convergence of bounded linear positive operators $T_n :L_1(m)\rightarrow L_1(m)$.

- In general terms, the technique can be described as follows: For each $n\in\mathbb{N}$, define  $M_nf=\max_{1\leq j\leq n}T_jf$ and $Mf:=\sup_n T_n f$.

> ***Proposition I:*** If $M$ is of  weak-type $(1,1)$, that is, there is $C>0$ such that
> $$\begin{align}
> \sup_{\lambda>0}\lambda m(M|f|>\lambda)\leq C\|f\|_1,\qquad f\in L_1(m),\tag{1}\label{type11}
> \end{align}$$
> and $T_ng\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} g$ poitwise for all functions $g$ in some $\mathcal{G}\subset L_1(m)$, then $T_nf$ converges to $f$ a.s. for all $f$ in the closure $\overline{\mathcal{G}}$ of $\mathcal{G}$ in $L_1$.

The proof of this fact is standard in Analysis. I present a sketch in the addendum.

- The converse also holds for example when operators $T_n$ on $L_1(\mathbb{T})$ are translation invariant.

> ***Proposition II:*** If $T_nf(x)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} f(x)$ almost surely for any $f\in L_1(\mathbb{T})$, and $T_n$ commute with translations,  then $M$ is of weak-type $(1,1)$.

Results of this kind are more delicate.  Known results in this direction are  [Stein's maximal principle](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970308?origin=crossref&seq=1),  and [Swayer's theorem](https://www.jstor.org/stable/1970516?seq=1) (hence our choice of $L_1(\mathbb{T})$). On the real line, there is a result for certain type of convolution operators (just like the ones we have $T_nf=f*\mu_n$ for compactly supported measures) for which a weak-type (1,1) inequality holds (See Harmonic Analysis, Stein, E., chapter X).

- With these tools at our disposal, we can show that the collection of $f\in L_1$ for which $f_n=\tau_{\alpha_n}f$ does not converge to $f$ point wise almost surely (that is,  the $f\in L_1$ for which $m(f_n\stackrel{n}{\nrightarrow} f)>0$) is not empty. For this, it is enough to show that the maximal funciton$M:f\mapsto Mf=\sup_n|\tau_{a_n}f|$ does not satisfy a weak-type (1,1) maximal inequality. This is equivalent to showing  that for any $m\in\mathbb{N}$, there is a function $f_m\in L_1(\mathbb{T})$ such that $\|f_m\|_1\leq1$ and
  $$ \sup_{t>0}t \,m(|Mf_m|>t)\geq m\|f\|_1$$
  Without loss of generality, assume $1\geq a_n\searrow0$, i.e. $0<a_{n+1}<a_n\leq1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $a_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$

(Due to Anthony Quas:) For each $k$, let $\beta_k>0$ so that
$$\beta_k<\min_{1\leq j\leq k}(a_{j-1}-a_j)$$
and define $f_k:=\mathbb{1}_{[0,\beta_k]}$ so that $\|f_k\|_1=\beta_k<1$. Then,  the  sets $[a_0,\beta_k+a_0],\ldots [a_k,\beta_k+a_k]$ are pairwise disjoint and so
$M_kf_k(x)=\max_{1\leq j\leq k}\tau_{a_j}f_k(x)=1$ on $\bigcup^k_{j=0}[a_j,a_j+\beta_k]$; hence
$$\sup_{t>0}t m(Mf_k>t)\geq k\|f_k\|_1$$
This means that  $$\sup_{\|f\|_1=1}\sup_{t>0}t\, m(Mf>t)=\infty$$
Proposition II implies the existence of $f\in L_1(\mathbb{T})$ for which \eqref{zero} holds.

---

**Observation:** It may be possible to use the functions $f_k$ defined above to construct an *explicit* function $f\in L_1(\mathbb{T})$ satisfying \eqref{zero} and from this, obtain a bounded measurable function $\phi$ as above.

---

**Addendum:** (*Sketch of proof of Prop. I*) For $f\in \overline{\mathcal{G}}$, choose $\{\phi_n:n\in\mathbb{N}\}\subset \mathcal{G}$ such that $\|f-\phi_n\|_1\leq \frac1n$.
Then
$$
|T_kf-f|=|T_k(f-\phi_n)-(f-\phi_n)|+T_k\phi_n-\phi_n|\leq M|f-\phi_n|+|f-\phi_n|+|T\phi_n-\phi_n|
$$
Setting $T_*f=\limsup_k|T_kf-f|$, and noticing that $T_*\phi_n=$ for all $n$, we obtain that
$$
T_*f\leq M|f-\phi_n|+|f-\phi_n|
$$
for all $n$. Then, from \eqref{type11} and Chebyshev-Markov's inequality
$$
m(T_*f>2\lambda)\leq m(M|f-\phi_n|>\lambda)+m(|f-\phi_n|>\lambda)\leq\frac{(C+1)}{n\lambda}\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0
$$
As a consequence $\lim_nT_nf(x)=f(x)$ for $m$-almost all $x$. In particular, of $\mathcal{G}$ is dense in $L_1$, then for any $f\in L_1(m)$, $T_nf(x)\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty} f(x)$ almost surely.

Comment: I tried a lot but I couldn't understand your answer, one year later I will try again! :)

Comment: My solution is not an elementary one. I am using a strong result from analysis that says that one has a sequence of linear operators $T_n$ on $L_1$ (In your case $T_nf(x)=f(x-a_n)$, and $T_nf$ converges pointwise almost surely for all $f\in L_1$, then the maximal function $Mf(x)=\sup_nT_nf(x)$ must satisfy an inequality of the form $m(\{x:|Mf(x)|>t\})\leq c\frac{\|f\|_1}{t}$ for al $f\in L_1$ and $t>0$ ($c$ is a constant). What I showed is that for the operators $T_nf(x)=f(x-a_n)$ of your problem, the maximal function does not satisfy such and inequality.

Comment: The reason I didn't choose H. H. Rugh's answer because I didn't understand it *at all*! But at least I partially understood your answer so why I commented I'll come back to read, esp I will continue analysis for my postgraduate.

Answer (score 1):

**Attention** Till now no one has succeed to find an answer to the OP at the level of Brucker's book as requested by the OP. My answer is the closest one to the OP at the level of Brucker's book.

This answer presents two "partial solutions".  The first one is:

> A bounded measurable function on $[0, 1]$ and a sequence  $a_n$ of positive numbers converging to zero, such that the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=f (x − a_n )$ is not a.e. convergent to f.

**Attention**: Here we use a fat Cantor set $F$ and the sequence $a_n$  does not depend on the point $x \in F$. However, it is not a complete solution to the OP, since the sequence is not arbitrary.

Let us go step by step.

1. Using representation in base 3, Cantor set $C$ can be described as the set of elements of $[0,1]$ that have at least one representation not using the digit $1$ (remember that rational numbers have two representations, while irrational number have only one).
   It is easy to see that the measure of the excluded set is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{n-1}}{3^n} =1$. So $\lambda(C)=0$.
2. A simple way to produce a fat Cantor set is to define $F$ the set of elements of $[0,1]$ that have at least one representation not containing the sequence $11$. In this case, the measure of the excluded set is $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{2^{n-1}}{3^{n+1}} =\frac{1}{3}$. So $\lambda(F)=\frac{2}{3}$.

Note that if one representation of a rational number contains the sequence $111$ , then both representations contain the sequence $11$.  For instance, consider $r= 0.2111$ then the other representation is  $r= 0.21102222 \dots$. Both representations contain the sequence $11$. So, if $y \in [0,1]$ and one representation of $y$ contains the sequence $111$, then $y \notin F$.

Now let us define the sequence $(a_n)_n$.

The fist 26 elements are $a_1=0.001$ till $a_{26}=0.222$.

The next 26 elements are $a_{27}=0.0001$ till $a_{52}=0.0222$.

The next 26 elements are $a_{53}=0.00001$ till $a_{78}=0.00222$.

And so on.

It is clear that $a_n$ converges to $0$.

Let $x \in F$, consider the sequence $x-a_n$. It is easy to see that given any $N \in \Bbb N$, there is $n>N$ such that one representation of  $x-a_n$ contains $111$.  So, $x-a_n \notin F$.

Let $f$ be the indicator function of $F$. Then, for all $x \in F$, $f(x)=1$. But, from the previous paragraph, we have that  given any $N \in \Bbb N$, there is $n>N$ such that  $x-a_n \notin F$, that means $f(x-a_n)=0$.

So, for all $x \in F$,
$f(x-a_n)$ does not converge to $f$.

Since $\lambda(F) > 0$, the functions $f_n(x)= f(x-a_n)$ do not converge a.e to $f$.

---

Here is a second "partial solution". It presents:

> For any sequence  $a_n$ of positive numbers converging to zero, a bounded function on $[0, 1]$ such that the sequence of functions $f_n(x)=f (x − a_n )$ is not a.e. convergent to f.

**Attention**: Although the sequence $a_n$ is arbitrary, this is not a complete solution to the OP, because $f$ will, in general, not be measurable.

The idea is, given any sequence of positive  numbers converging to zero, to build a Vitalli set $G$ adapted to the sequence.

Given any sequence  $(a_n)_n$ of positive  numbers converging to zero, let

$$S=\left\{ \sum_{k=0}^m p_k a_{n_k}: (a_{n_k})_k \text { is a finite set of elements in the sequence } (a_n)_n \text { and } \\ p_k \in \Bbb Z \text{, for all } k\in \Bbb N \right\}$$ Of course, $0 \in S$ (empty addition) and for each $n$, $a_n \in S$. It is easy to see that $S$ is countable.

Let us define $\sim$  in $[0,1]$ by $x \sim y$ if and only if $x-y \in S$. It is easy to see that $\sim$ is an equivalence relation.

Let us choose exactly one element of each equivalence class. Let $G$ be the such chosen elements.

Note that  $[0,1] \subseteq \bigcup_{s \in S} (G+s)$ and that, for all $s \in S$, $\lambda^*(G+s) = \lambda^*(G)$. It follows that $\lambda^*(G)>0$.

Let $f$ be the indicator function of $G$. It follows that, for every $x\[0,1]$ if $f(x)=1$ then $x \in G$ and then, for all $n \in \Bbb N$, $x-a_n \notin G$, so $f(x-a_n) =0$. So $f_n(x)=f(x-a_n)$ does not converge pointwise to $f$ on $G$, and since $\lambda^*(G)>0$, we have that $f_n$ does not converge to $f$.

Note that $f$ is a bounded function, but it is not measurable.

Comment: it seems that the problem in the OP's is to find, for a given positive sequence $a_n\rightarrow0$, a measurable function $f$ such that $f_n(x)=f(x-a_n)$ does not converge to $f$ a.s. That could mean that $f$ fails to converge to $f$ in a set of positive measure.

Comment: I added the construction of a fat cantor set represented by the book, also the book meant by $a_n$ an arbitrary sequence of positive numbers converges to $0$. If there is any solution available especially not using ternary system you provided (which is hard to follow even though very clear written) and probably considering an arbitrary seq.?

Comment: After defining S, shouldn't we consider instead $S'=S \cap [0,1]$ for the rest of the argument?

Comment: @L.G. We could consider only $S'= S \cap [-1,1]$. We need the negative numbers for the symmetry of the equivalence relation.  However, since de space is clearly $[0,1]$, we don't need to restrict $S$.

Comment: Hi Ramiro, I could find one of the authors' emails and I sent this link of OP for him the other day writing "unlike other exercises of your book Real Analysis, it seems there is no simple solution for Exercise 4:3.3 at the scope of the book"..., he replied today : " Since there is a bounty on the question on StackExchange it would not be appropriate to offer you any hints. In any case it has been over twenty years since we wrote the book and I don't remember the source.  Probably the hint in the text works".

Comment: @L.G. Nice. Once the bounty is over, you may try contact the author again. But, as he has already said, he will probably not remember this exercise or its source.

Comment: @JeanLeider  My answer is the most closed answer at the level of Brucker's book.  I clearly state in my answer that is not a complete solution to the OP. You should not dowvote my answer.

Comment: @JeanLeider Till now no one has succeed to find an answer to the OP at the level of Brucker's book as requested by the OP. My answer is the answer  closest to the level of Brucker's book. It is unfair to downvote an answer without understanding the context.

Comment: @OliverDiaz My two solutions and Rugh's one are adequate to the level of Bruck's book. In my answer, I covered the **two** variants that seem to fit the supposed level of the exercise. In my answer there is no false advertising at all and, in the **attention** sections, I clearly explain where each solution does not completely satisfies de OP.

Comment: @OlivierDiaz It is worth to note that in Bruck's book this exercise is not even marked as a difficult one. So clearly, it is meant to be answered using only basic machinery in the scope of the book.

Comment: @JeanLeider, I have seen lots of answers each mentions that it's not a complete answer (sometimes they are written in answer section even if they are not a partial answer as well, mostly because comments are narrow to contain). I believe, any useful information should be acknowledged (in MSE by upvoting or saying "thank you") not the contrary. If I get a complete answer I will happily transfer the accept to that one still I am very happy to bounty such a useful information. Kind regards.

Answer (score 1):

Say, that a set $A\subset [0,1]$ is uniformly "porous" if to every $\Delta>0$ and every interval $I$ of length $\Delta$ there is $\delta=\delta(\Delta)>0$ so that
$I\setminus A$ contains an interval of length $\delta$. In other words, $A$ has "holes" of length $\delta$ that are $\Delta$-dense.

A typical construction of a fat Cantor-set has this uniform porosity property, e.g the set described on the page [wiki fat cantor set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set).

Let  $N_\Delta=\lceil \Delta/\delta\rceil$ and let $\tau_a(x)=x+a$ be the translation by $a>0$. The porosity property implies that
for every $\Delta>0$: $$ \bigcap_{k=0}^{N_\Delta-1} \tau^k_\delta(A) = \emptyset.$$
Thus, every point in $A$ will at some point go into a hole by one of the translations $\tau_\delta,...,\tau_{(N_\Delta-1)\delta}$. Now, choose (arbitrarily) a sequence $\Delta_n \to 0^+$ and let $\delta_n=\delta(\Delta_n)>0$, $N_n= N_{\Delta_n}$ be the corresponding data for the associated holes. Define $(a_j)_{j\geq 1}$ to be the sequence obtained by juxtaposing the "chunks" $(\delta_n,2\delta_n,...(N_n-1)\delta_n)$ starting from the left with $n=1$.
By construction, $a_j\to 0$ as $j\to +\infty$.

Let $f={\bf 1}_A$ be the characteristic function of $A$.
Then, for every point $x\in A$, the sequence $(f(x+a_j))_{j\geq 0}$ contains
infinitely many zeros, i.e. there is no point  $x\in A$ for which the sequence converges to $f(x)=1$. This follow from the fact that arbitrarily far out in the sequence you will find a chunk for which one of the translates will belong to a hole of $A$.

Comment: Is $A$ measurable?

Comment: @L.G. You may take it to be measurable but in fact, the statement holds without assuming measurability.

Comment: @OliverDiaz Yes, for $A$ one could take e.g. the fat Cantor set in the link.

Comment: I need A to be measurable for starters so fits the hypothesis the problem, thanks a lot for your answer but still very complicated; may I comeback after a week so first take care of my exam I've then try a day or two to learn your answer as much as possible, then taking your time asking the details?

Comment: @L.G. Yes, also in the exercise it is asked for a measurable function $f$ (in which case $A$ of course should be measurable).

Comment: Thanks, H. H. Rugh :)

Comment: @H.H.Rugh In fact, the exercise asks for, given any sequence $a_n$ converging to $0$, find a bounded measurable function $f$ such that ... which seems to make the exercise much harder.

Comment: @Ramiro  Yes, I became aware when you changed your post. I hadn't noticed before. Indeed this makes the problem much harder. Given that it comes from a book of Bruckner the statement with hint is a.s. correct and there is probably some nice trick to solve it.

Comment: Hi @H.H.Rugh, here is [a problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4559503/121671) that may be if interest to you. It requires probably some symbolic dynamics.