# $f$ continuous with summable Fourier coefficients $\implies$ Fourier series converges to $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-series

Suppose that $f$ is continuous and has (absolute) summable Fourier coefficients:
$$
\sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}}\vert  c_k \vert < \infty.
$$
Is it then true that the Fourier series for $f$ converges to $f$ pointwise?

I have tried to search on this site and on Google for an answer but couldn't find it. I believe that at least it does converge but I am not sure that it has to be to $f$.

I am not necessarily looking for a proof, just a clarification on whether or not this is true.

Comment: It seems likely that the poster's odd phrase "(absolute) summable Fourier coefficients" is meant in the sense that the Fourier series $\frac {a_0} {2} + \sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (a_k \cos kt + b_k \sin kt)$ has the property that $\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} (|a_k| +| b_k|) < \infty$.  If so the series converges uniformly to the function.

Comment: @B.S.Thomson: this is an unrelated question, but since I realize you participate here (MSE) and I got introduced to tour books (with Buckner^2( I would like to ask if there is (or if you remember) an easy solution to this problem in your [book](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4106171/121671) I found a not so trivial solution resorting to the machinery of ergodic theory, but it still bugs me that there might be a much simpler solution. Sorry for intruding like the.

Comment: @OliverDíaz  Don't remember what we had in mind.  The hint plus Egorov's theorem is most likely what we intended.  (That is no gurantee that it was correct.)

Comment: @B.S.Thomson: Thanks fo your answer, that is what I thought (that the problem is more complicated than initially thought).

Comment: @B.S.Thomson I have clarified what I meant with absolute summable Fourier coefficients

Comment: @StefanLafon: now that the OP has clarified his posting, you may want to consider rewriting your answer. maybe a few edits.