# Is there a set $E$ such that for every open interval $I$, $0<m(I\cap E)<m(I)$?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Is it possible for there to be a measurable set $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}$ such that for every open interval $I$, $0<m(I\cap E)<m(I)$ (where $m$ is the Lebesgue measure of a set)?

The first thing I notice is that this set must be dense, since if it were not dense we would be able to find an interval with no members of $E$.  It of course also must be uncountable in size, since it cannot have zero measure itself.  It is also pretty clear that $\mathbb{R}\setminus E$ must also have this property if $E$ has this property.

Aside from that I'm stumped.  I've tried a couple of toy sets but they all turned out to not have this property.  Then I tried to show no set could have this property but I hit a brick wall pretty quickly.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57317/construction-of-a-borel-set-with-positive-but-not-full-measure-in-each-interval/57326#57326

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EDITED:

Hint: it suffices to prove for countably many open intervals with rational endpoints.  Construct your set as the union of a sequence of ["fat Cantor sets"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smith%E2%80%93Volterra%E2%80%93Cantor_set).

Comment: Sorry, I did mean something else.  Editing...

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57317/construction-of-a-borel-set-with-positive-but-not-full-measure-in-each-interval/57326#57326