# Given $0<a<1$, construct a Borel set with $\mu(A∩I)/\mu(I)=a$ for each open interval $I$

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Construction of a Borel set with positive but not full measure in each interval was discussed in this post [Construction of a Borel set with positive but not full measure in each interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57317/construction-of-a-borel-set-with-positive-but-not-full-measure-in-each-interval).

Here I am interested in a finer version. If $\mu$ denotes Lebesgue measure, given $0<a<1$, how would one construct a Borel set $A\subset R$ such that
$\mu(A\cap I)/\mu(I)=a$
for every open interval $I$ in $R$?

For simplicity, I am interested in the case where the $R$ above is replaced with the unit interval.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Such a construction contradicts the Lebesgue density theorem, which implies that the limit

$$\lim_{\mu(I) \to 0, x \in I} \frac{\mu(A \cap I)}{\mu(I)} = \chi_A(x)$$

almost everywhere, so $a$ would have to be zero or one.