# Can we partition $[0,1]$ into two nowhere null sets?

Tags: measure-theory

Is it possible to partition $[0, 1] = A \sqcup B$ such that given any $0 \leq x < y \leq 1$, both $\mu([x,y] \cap A) > 0$ and $\mu([x,y] \cap B) > 0$?

Comment: Hi Zach, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I've tried a few different things, but nothing seems to work. I don't know if I have the necessary knowledge to figure this out yet, as I have just started learning measure theory on my own.

Comment: See the answers to: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57317/construction-of-a-borel-set-with-positive-but-not-full-measure-in-each-interval?lq=1