# Strictly positive bound on an open set for non-negative $L^{\infty}$-function.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, lp-spaces

Assume that a non-negative function $f \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ for some open set $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb{R}^n$ is given. Does there exist an open set $\mathcal{O} \subseteq \Omega$ and a constant $K>0$ such that $f \geq K$ is valid almost everywhere on $\mathcal{O}$?

I think this is the case, but unfortunately have not yet found a good argument for it. So far I have two approaches:

1. Since $f$ is bounded, one can find a sequence of simple functions $f_n : \Omega \to [0,\infty)$ such that $f_n \leq f_{n+1}$ and $f_n \to f$ uniformly on $\Omega$ apply. In particular, it follows that $f_n \leq f$ holds. Suppose that every $f_n$ has the representation
   \begin{equation*}
   f_n = \sum_{k=0}^{N_n} c_k^n \chi_{E_k^n}
   \end{equation*}
   with $c_0^n = 0$. Here one can exclude sets $E_k^n \subseteq \Omega$ with Lebesgue measure $0$.  If one can now show that there is an $n \in \mathbb{N}$ and a $k \in \{1, \dots, N_n\}$ such that $\mathcal{O} \subseteq E_k^n$ for an open set $\mathcal{O} \subseteq \Omega$, then one would have shown the assertion.
2. We choose a set $A \subseteq \Omega$ with $\lambda(A) > 0$ such that $f > 0$ holds everywhere on $A$. This can be achieved by using another representative of $f$.
   If we now define for each $n \in \mathbb{N}$ the set
   \begin{equation*}
   M_n = \left \{ x \in A \: \Big| \: 2^{-n-1} \| f \|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}  < f(x) \leq 2^{-n} \| f \|_{L^{\infty}(\Omega)}  \right\},
   \end{equation*}
   at least one set must have Lebesgue measure greater than $0$. Now my idea would be to use the regularity of the Lebesgue measure to show that an open set $\mathcal{O}$ with $\mathcal{O} \subseteq M_n$ exists.

I am grateful for any hints.

Comment: You probably want $\mathcal O$ to be nonempty?

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57317/construction-of-a-borel-set-with-positive-but-not-full-measure-in-each-interval. The indicator function of such a set A is a counter example.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer! This seems to answer my question. Out of curiosity, are there any criteria, apart from continuity, that a function must fulfil in order to satisfy the above property?