# Clarification on Constructing a Dense Borel Set that is Positive Measure but not Full Measure on Each Interval

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, solution-verification, proof-explanation, dense-subspaces

I recently came across this exact same question asked here: [Construction of a Borel set with positive but not full measure in each interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57317/construction-of-a-borel-set-with-positive-but-not-full-measure-in-each-interval) :

> If $\mu$ denotes Lebesgue measure, how would one construct a Borel set $A \subset \mathbb{R}$ such that
> $$0 < \mu(A \cap I) < \mu(I)$$
> for every interval $I$ in $\mathbb{R}$?

The answer with the highest vote seems to suggest the set $A$ constructed there is sufficient. I will copy-paste the answer for convinience:

> Let $\{r_n\}$ be an enumeration of the rationals, let $V_1$ be a segment of finite length centered at $r_1$, and let $V_n$ be a segment of length $m(V_{n-1})/3$ centered at $r_n$. Set
> $$
> W_n=V_n-\bigcup_{k=1}^{\infty}V_{n+k},
> $$
> and observe that
> \begin{equation}
> m(W_n)\geq m(V_n)-\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}m(V_{n+k})=m(V_n)-m(V_n)\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}3^{-k}=\frac{m(V_n)}{2}.
> \end{equation}
> In particular, $m(W_n)>0$.
> For each $n$, choose a Borel set $A_n\subset W_n$ with $0<m(A_n)<m(W_n)$. Finally, put $A=\bigcup_{n=1}^{\infty}A_n$. Because $A_n\subset W_n$ and the $W_n$ are disjoint,  $m(A\cap W_n)=m(A_n)$. That is to say,
> $$
> 0<m(A\cap W_n)<m(W_n)
> $$
> for every $n$. But every interval contains a $W_n$, so $A$ meets the criteria, and has finite measure (specifically, $m(A)\leq\sum_n m(V_n)=2 m(V_1)<\infty$).
> In particular, we must have for all interval $I$,
> $$
> 0 < m(A \cap I) < m(I).
> $$

Now I can show why $0 < m(A \cap I)$ is true: Since every interval $I$ must contain some constructed rational centered interval $V_n$, we have as $A_n \subseteq W_n \subseteq V_n$ for all $n \in \mathbf{N}$,
$$
m(I \cap A) \geq m(V_n \cap A) = \sum_{i = 1} ^\infty m(V_n \cap A_i) \geq m(V_n \cap A_n) = m(A_n) > 0.
$$
**But I can not seem to prove**
$$
m(I \cap A) < m(I).
$$
Any suggestions as to how to proceed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was not mentioned but of course this holds for nonempty intervals.

Let $I$ be a nonempty interval. Then it contains $W_n$ for some integer $n$, and
$$
\begin{align}
m(A\cap I)
&=m(A\cap W_n)+m(A\cap(I\backslash W_n))\\
&<m(W_n)+m(A\cap(I\backslash W_n))\\
&\le m(I)+m(I\backslash W_n)\\
&=m(I).
\end{align}
$$