# Rudin Real and Complex Analysis Exercise 2.8

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-sets

> Construct a Borel set $E$ in $\mathbb{R}^1$ such that $$0<m(E \cap I)<m(I)$$ for every nonempty segment $I$. Is it possible to have $m(E)<\infty$ for such a set?

I wonder how can I construct a set like this, though I've read the solution. Can someone tell me what leads to the construction of this set and what's the idea? I'll appreciate it. (The measure $m$ is the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}^1$)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Construction of a Borel set with positive but not full measure in each interval](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/57317/construction-of-a-borel-set-with-positive-but-not-full-measure-in-each-interval)

Comment: Thank you so much! Sorry for not searching the site thoroughly.