# If $\int_a^b f(x) \ dx > 0$ then $f(x) > 0$ a.e?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $f$ be a measurable nonnegative function with domain $\mathbb{R}$, such that
\begin{equation}
\int_a^b f(x) \ dx > 0
\end{equation}
when $a < b$. Can we say that $f>0$ almost everywhere? (or $f\neq 0$ almost everywhere, because is a nonnegative function)

We work with Lebesgue measure and the integral above is a Lebesgue integral.

I'm thinking that the answer is yes, but I can't prove it.

I tried to get a contradiction if I suppose that $m(\{ f=0 \}) > 0$, or maybe a subset of $\{ f=0 \}$ with measure greater than $0$, but I got stuck.

I already showed that for any open set $G$ we have
\begin{equation}
\int_G f(x) \ dx > 0
\end{equation}
So maybe I could find an open set $G$ such that $m(G) = m(\{ f=0 \})$, but I can't.

And that's it, I have no more ideas :(

Thanks

Comment: The answer is of course, negative. $f = 1_{[a,b-r]}$

Comment: One extreme counterexample is the indicator function of a set which has "positive but not full measure in every interval", in which case there is not even a nontrivial interval in which $f > 0$ a.e. [Here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3136074/473276) is my favourite construction of such a set.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No: let $X \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ be a fat Cantor set and let $f$ be a function that is $0$ on $X$ and $1$ elsewhere. Since $X$ is nowhere dense, $\int_a^b f\, dx>0$ for all $a<b$ since $[a,b] \setminus X$ will contain a nontrivial interval. At the same time, by definition the set where $f$ vanishes has positive measure.

Comment: This also shows why our intuition can be misleading. The (wrong) proofs I were imaging involved finding a contradiction with $f$ vanishing on an interval. But "not measure zero" does not mean "contains an interval." My brain still wants to believe that even after knowing about the Cantor set.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the fat Cantor set (don't judge me)