# What is the intuition behind the notion of strong differentiation?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, analysis

> ${\bf definition.}$ A function $f$ defined on open set $A \subseteq
>  \mathbb{R}$ is said to be ${\bf strong \; differentiable}$ at $a \in
>  A$ if
>
> $$ \lim_{(x_1,x_2)  \to (a,a) \\  x_1 \neq x_2 } \dfrac{ f(x_1)-f(x_2)
>  }{x_1-x_2} = f^{*}(a)$$
>
> exists and is finite and we call $f^*(a)$ the strong derivative of $f$
>   at $x=a$

How is this notion different than the usual derivative?  I mean, if we set $x_2 = a$, we get our usual derivative...

What is the point of such definition? what is motivation for this?

Comment: See [“Strong” derivative of a monotone function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85069/strong-derivative-of-a-monotone-function) ***AND*** [What does the continuity of $f'$ tell us about $f$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1574384) ***AND*** [Differences between derivatives and strong derivatives](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1675246) ***AND*** [Derivatives as defined by a two variable difference quotient limit](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/188869) ***AND*** [Alternative definition of derivative](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2095094).

Comment: In particular if  $f$ is differentiable on $B$ where  $B$ is open and $a\in B\subset A$ then by the MVT, $f$ is strong differentiable at $a$ iff $f'(x) $ is continuous at $x=a.$