# Does a such condition imply differentiability?

Tags: calculus, analysis, derivatives

Let function $f:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be such that

$$
 \lim_{\Large{(y,z)\rightarrow (x,x) \atop y\neq z}} \frac{f(y)-f(z)}{y-z}=0.
$$
Is it then $f'(x)=0$ ?

Comment: And what do you think about it?

Comment: I would be curious to see you expand the haiku-like accepted answer into a detailed proof. For example, "to take $z=x$ in the double limit", as you suggest in a comment, is a pretty sure way to get a wrong solution.

Comment: For the record, the limiting notion you've asked about is called the *strong derivative*, and you can find more than you'd ever want to know about it in my answer [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85069/strong-derivative-of-a-monotone-function).

Comment: @Did:I added a detailed proof. Can you please explain to me where I am wrong?

Comment: @P.. The detailed proof works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is $f'(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{y\to x}\dfrac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$?

---

Let $\epsilon>0$. From the hypothesis it follows that exists a $\delta>0$ such that if $y\neq z$ and $0<\|(y,z)-(x,x)\|<\delta$ then $\left|\dfrac{f(y)-f(z)}{y-z}\right|<\epsilon$.

Now if $0<|y-x|<\delta$ then $0<\|(y,x)-(x,x)\|=|y-x|<\delta$ and $y\neq x$.

Therefore $\left|\dfrac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}\right|<\epsilon$.

It follows that $f'(x)=\displaystyle\lim_{y\to x}\dfrac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}=0.$

Comment: Thanks. Now I understand, in the double limit we could take $z=x$.