# A continuous function for which Lebesgue’s Differentiation Theorem doesn’t hold for Rectangles?

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure, examples-counterexamples

Lebesgue's differentiation theorem states that if $x$ is a point in $\mathbb{R}^n$ and $f:\mathbb{R}^n\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ is a Lebesgue integrable function, then the limit of $\frac{\int_B f d\lambda}{\lambda(B)}$ over all balls $B$ centered at $x$ as the diameter of $B$ goes to $0$ is equal almost everywhere to $f(x)$.  But if you replace balls with other kinds of set with diameter going to $0$, this need not be true.  For instance it need not be true if you replace balls with rectangles.

But [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1407.2138.pdf) says that if we restrict things to continuous functions with compact support, then Lebesgue’s differentiation holds true for rectangles.  My question is, what is an example of a continuous function (without compact support) for which Lebesgue’s theorem doesn’t hold for rectangles?

Comment: You  have some misunderstandings. Read about sets ''shrinking nicely to a point'' in Rudin's RCA.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy What misunderstandings do I have?

Comment: This question was recently bumped to the main questions page, where I just now saw it, probably for the first time. In case you're still interested in this topic, see the last paragraph (added about 10 months ago) to my answer to [Is there a garden of derivatives?](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/837286/13130)