# What different definitions of derivatives exist?

Tags: calculus, differential-topology, vector-analysis, functional-calculus

Eventhough the concept of the derivative is always the same, there exist different ways of stating it and generalising it.

My question is: What different definitions of the derviative exist and in which context do they make sense?

For example, one of the definitions of the derivative is the *Fréchet derivative*, which is defined on *Banach spaces*.

Comment: There are many *generalizations* of the base concept. For example we call 'derivation' every linear transformation on a Lie algebra which satisfies (a version of) the Leibniz rule.

Comment: @Berci That's exactly what I'm looking for!

Comment: See [Is there a garden of derivatives?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/833735/13130) *AND* [Most general definition of differentiation](https://mathoverflow.net/q/347590/15780).

Answer (score 1):

One rather axiomatic approach is that you call any operator $D$ a derivative that is

1. Linear:

   - $D(\alpha f) = \alpha Df$
   - $D(f+g) = Df+Dg$
2. Obeys Leibniz' Rule:

   - $D(fg)=fDg + gDf$

For "scalars" $\alpha$ and "functions" $f$, $g$.  This allows to define derivatives even for functions that operate on discrete sets$^1$ where no concepts like limes or completeness are available.  All you need is "addition" and "multiplication", both commutative$^2$.

That is the scalars are $\def\M{\mathcal S} \alpha\in \M=(\M,+,\cdot)$, functions are $f\in \{\M\to\M\}$, and functionals are $D\in \{\{\M\to\M\} \to \{\M\to\M\}\}$

---

$^1$Not to be confused with *discrete derivative*.

$^2$Where the latter condition could be dropped. In that case you'll come up with different flavours.

Comment: Cool! Do you know who came up with this definition?

Comment: No.  But good overview is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_the_derivative for different approaches to derivative. There are also axiomatic approaches to Lie derivative or Exterior derivative, just to name two.