# Soft Question - Generalizations of the Derivative

Tags: functions, derivatives, differential-algebra, derivations

This is a soft question. I'm asking for any interesting and rather unknown generlizations of the derivative. I know it is generalized through derivations which are functions $\delta$ satisfying
$$\delta(uv) = v\delta(u) + u\delta(v)$$
Some of them include for example, q-derivatives used in quantum calculus
$$\left(\frac{d}{dx}\right)_qf(x) = \frac{f(qx)- f(x)}{qx-x}$$
The arithmetic derivative used in number theory
$$D(n) = n\sum_{p\mid n}\frac{\nu_p(n)}{p}$$
The Hasse derivative
$$D^{(r)}X^n = {n\choose r}X^{n-r}$$
and many more...
I'm asking if anyone knows any interesting and perhaps relatively unknown generalizations of the derivative/examples of interesting derivations. Feel free to share anything you feel is interesting

Comment: You may be interested in fractional derivatives. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_calculus

Comment: I believe a “$\lim_{q\to 1}$” is missing at the r.h.s. of $(\Bbb d/\Bbb dx)_q f(x)$.

Comment: Also, there is this thing (I don’t know if it has a symbol already): $$\lim_{q\to1} \frac {f(x^q)-f(x)} {x^q-x}.$$

Comment: @Rócherz the limit isn't part of the definition of the q-derivative, as taking the limit as q goes to 1 would result in the standard derivative

Comment: @Rócherz Do you know where the one you mentioned above is used/where it is from?

Comment: See my answer to [Is there a garden of derivatives?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/833735/13130) However, nearly all of the variations I mention in my answer have essentially the same algebraic difference quotient at their core/nucleus.

Comment: I'm not sure this is what you're looking for, but differential geometry is littered with derivative generalizations - covariant derivative, Lie derivatives, exterior derivatives, interior derivative etc.

Comment: You may be interested in the [Radon–Nikodym derivative](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_theorem#Radon%E2%80%93Nikodym_derivative) as a measure theoretic generalization of the Jacobian.

Comment: Actually, it looks like there's a whole [Wikipedia article](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generalizations_of_the_derivative) on the topic of this question.

Comment: The boundary operator in topology acts sort of like a derivative.

Comment: @C-RAM yeah that's what prompted the question. I'm looking for rather unknown ones out of curiosity :)

Comment: Combinatorial species (https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combinatorial_species) have a differentiation operator. They also have a generating function that is a formal series; differentiating the combinatorial species is equivalent to derivating the series. It is however similar to the derivative in type theory listed in the Wikipedia page about Generalizations of derivative, except that it is used in combinatorics rather than in computer science.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Which makes for an interesting discussion, because the topology derivative does not follow $\delta(uv) = v\delta(u) + u\delta(v)$ - there is a minus sign, which explains why $\delta^2=0$, in that case.

Comment: @Jean-ArmandMoroni, yes, this is also true of the exterior derivative, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exterior_derivative

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two made-up cases.

**1) Acting on elements one at a time**

$d$ applies a function $f$ on elements of a subset $A$, outputting a set of copies of $A$ where in each copy, one $x$ is replaced by $f(x)$.
Example: $d(\{a,b,c\}) = \{\{f(a), b, c\}, \{a, f(b), c\}, \{a, b, f(c)\}\}$
Quite intuitive, but the precise definition is somewhat tedious:
For any $f: E \to E$, define
$d: \mathcal P(E) \to \mathcal P (\mathcal P(E))$ with $d(A) = \{(A \setminus \{x\}) \cup f(x) , x \in A\}$
Then $d(A \sqcup B) = (d(A) \otimes B) \cup (d(B) \otimes A) $
where $\otimes: (\mathcal P (\mathcal P(E)), \mathcal P(E)) \to \mathcal P (\mathcal P(E))$, $X \otimes Y = \{ x \cup Y, x \in X \}$.

A similar one, **cutting one element at a time**:
$d: \mathcal P(E) \to \mathcal P (\mathcal P(E))$ with $d(A) = \{(A \setminus \{x\}), x \in A\}$
Example: $d(\{a,b,c\}) = \{\{b,c\}, \{a,b\}, \{a,c\}\}$
This also verifies $d(A \sqcup B) = (d(A) \oplus B) \cup (d(B) \oplus A) $

This "cutting elements one at a time" is close to the derivative of simplices in algebraic topology: quickly said, the boundary of a $p$-simplex $S$ is the union of $p-1$ simplices, each one being $S$ minus one vertex. Except here we use plain sets, while simplices are oriented sets, and the boundary operator (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplex#Algebraic_topology), is an anti-derivation (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derivation_(differential_algebra)#Graded_derivations).

Note: working with sets means working with union, which is painfully not cancellative. Instead, we could work with multisets, or $\mathbb Z$-modules as in algebraic topology.

The principle of "cutting one element at a time" is at work on polynomials of $\mathbb C [X]$: decompose into a product of prime polynomials, and cross them one at a time.
Example: $((X-a)(X-b)(X-c))' = (X-b)(X-c) + (X-a)(X-c) + (X-a)(X-b)$.
The same process can be used for integers: this is the [arithmetic derivative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic_derivative) quoted in the OP.
$(30)' = (2 \times 3 \times 5)' = 3 \times 5 + 2 \times 5 + 2 \times 3 = 31$

**2) Multisets in $\mathbb R ^n$** (more fancy and conjectural)

Let $P_n$ be the set of finite multisets of points in $\mathbb R ^n$. Define $d: P_n \to P_n$,
$d(A) = \{$ equilibrium points of a set of forces in $\frac 1 r$ from points in $A \;\}$
(With the convention that for any point in $A$ with multiplicity $m$, there is an equilibrium point at the same place, with multiplicity $m-1$).

For $n=2$, identifying $\mathbb R^2$ with $\mathbb C$, if $A$ is the multiset of roots of polynomial $P$, then $d(A)$ is the multiset of roots of $P'$ (Bôcher's theorem: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%B4cher%27s_theorem). So it ensures $d$ behaves as a derivative.
Example: $d(\{1,i,-i\}) = \{\frac {1-i\sqrt2} 3, \frac {1+i\sqrt2} 3 \}$
Because $\{1,i,-i\}$ are the roots of $(X-1)(X^2+1)=X^3-X^2+X-1$, whose derivative is $3X^2-2X+1$, whose roots are $\{\frac {1-i\sqrt2} 3, \frac {1+i\sqrt2} 3 \}$.

We would like some kind of Leibniz rule: $d(A\otimes B) = d(A)\otimes B \oplus A\otimes d(B)$
As $\otimes$ corresponds to multiplication of polynomials, its definition is clear: it is union of multisets.
As $\oplus$ corresponds to addition of polynomials, however, it has no simple definition: roots of the sum of two polynomials have no simple relationship with the polynomials roots, except in specific cases (e.g. with two degree-1 polynomials, root of the sum is mean of the roots weighted by the coefficient on $X$). And we need to add a weight to our multisets, to account for the polynomial's highest degree coefficient.

But when $n>2\,$? Not even sure that $p$ points, each one with a force in $\frac 1 r$, have $p-1$ equilibrium points: I cannot find a proof nor a reference.
Of course for $n>2$ it works with $p$ points when $p\le 3$, or when the $p$ points are coplanar (in a 2-dimension plane); and probably also when the points are nearly coplanar, by a continuity argument.

Actually this could be extended to any distribution of masses in any subset (not necessarily finite) of $\mathbb R^n$; but how does the equilibrium set of an $\frac 1 r$ force from these masses would behave?

Comment: +1 Wow! This is really well explained and I've never come across these before. Very Interesting