# How to prove $f'(a)>0$ means $f$ is increasing?

Tags: real-analysis

I know that $f'(a)>0$ means $f$ is increasing in some open interval for the case $f$ is in class $C^1$.

pf) Choose $\epsilon := f'(a)/2$. For $f$ is in class $C^1$, $f'$ is continuous. By the definition of continuity, $\exists \delta >0, \forall x : |x-a|<\delta \Rightarrow |f'(x) - f'(a) | < \epsilon$. The last inequality with triangle inequality yields $f'(x)>0$ in some open interval and the proof is done.

The above statement and the proof is restricted on the class $C^1$, but I think it is not restricted, it is free from $C^1$ that $f'(a)>0$ means $f$ is increasing in some open interval.

How to prove it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At first, when learning a mathematical concept, there is likely to be a bit of a disconnect between your intuition and the definition.  Pursuing questions like this helps a lot.  Here you have answers that provide a wiggly function for a counterexample and a closer look at the proof for a continuous derivative.

Here is another viewpoint.  When you think of $f'(a)>0$ you commonly imagine all the difference quotients
$$\frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} $$
as positive for intervals $[x,y]$ close to $a$.  But the example here should remind you that $f'(a)>0$ only pays attention to the intervals $[x,y]$ that straddle $a$, i.e., intervals 
with $x \leq a \leq y$.  Not all intervals close.

The Italian mathematician Guiseppe Peano had a different response to this situation.  He felt that the ordinary derivative didn't convey the right intuitive idea.  Why shouldn't a positive "derivative" imply increasing close to the point?  He introduced what he called a *strict derivative* (nowadays called a *strong* derivative 
or *unstraddled* derivative by most people).  Define $f^\sharp(a)$ to
be the limit 
$$ f^\sharp(a) = \lim_{x,y\to a, x\not=y} \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x} $$
where now all intervals $[x,y]$ are being considered.  For this stronger derivative the answer to your question is positive: if $f^\sharp(a)>0$ then, indeed, $f$ is increasing in some neighborhood of the point $a$.  So you are right, but you were depending on the wrong derivative to supply your conclusion.

The original reference is

> Giuseppe Peano, Sur la definition de la derivee, Mathesis Recueil
>   Mathematique (2) 2 (1892), 12-14.

Peano hoped that the strict derivative would be useful in teaching calculus, but that hasn't worked out.  You can, however, find many papers that study this derivative.  It is a good introduction to the idea that there are numerous useful ways of defining a derivative other than the traditional calculus one.

Comment: For anyone who is interested in pursuing the literature on this topic, I posted quite a few references (and perhaps also the kitchen sink) in my answer to [“Strong” derivative of a monotone function](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85069/strong-derivative-of-a-monotone-function).

Answer (score 5):

A classic counter-example is $f(x)=x+x^2\sin(1/x^2)$ if $x\not = 0$, and $f(0)=0$. It is easy to see that $f$ is $C^1$ on $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$, with derivative $\displaystyle f^{\prime}(x)=1+2x\sin(1/x^2)-\frac{2}{x}\cos(1/x^2)$ and has for derivative $1$ at $0$. If $f$ is increasing in an interval $]-a,a[$, with $a>0$, then $f^{\prime}$ must be $\geq 0$ on such an interval, and we can easily see that this is not true.(Take $\displaystyle x_n=1/\sqrt{n\pi}$ for $n$ large and even).

Answer (score 1):

The problem with dropping continuity of $f'$ can be found in the proof. If you drop it you have not what is reqiuered to show that $f'(x)>0$ in an neighborhood of $a$.

Supposed we know that we mustn't have $f'(x)<0$ somewhere in the neighborhood (or an interval where $f'(x)=0$) we need to come up with an example where $f'(x)<0$ arbitrarily close to $a$. For example $f(x)=x+x^2(\sin1/x^2)$, but $f(0)=0$ is one - the exercise is to show that $f'(0) = 1$, and that it has negative derivates arbitrarily close to $0$.