# Properties of a function whose derivative is positive

Tags: real-analysis

I am trying to find a counter example to falsify the following statement:

"if $f$ is differentiable at $a$ and $f'(a)>0$, then $f(a)$ is increasing in a neighbourhood of $a$"

Comment: See Here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1499789/how-to-prove-fa0-means-f-is-increasing/1500182#1500182

Comment: Thank you! So is it true that on any *closed* interval for which $f'(a)$ is positive this statement will be true?

Comment: Sure, that follows from the mean value theorem.