# What does the continuity of $f'$ tell us about $f$?

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives, continuity

Suppose $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and its derivative $f'$ is continuous on the interval $[a,b]$. What constraints on $f$ would such condition give us?

Comment: Did you mean to ask "what constraints on $f'$ (the derivative of $f$) would follow? Because your title seems to be about properties of the derivative.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm wondering what the continuity of the derivative would tell us about the function $f$. It seems hard to me to relate this property back to $f$...

Comment: I suggest changing the title to something like: What does the continuity of $f'$ tell us about $f$? [the first phrase "a function which is a derivative of another function" seems vague, in referring to two functions without giving either a name.

Comment: Perhaps a better way to pose this would look like this:  *Suppose that $F:[a,b]\to\mathbb R$.  Find necessary and sufficient conditions on $F$ so that one may write $$F(x) = \int_a^x f(t)\,dt + C \ \ (a\leq x\leq b)$$ for some constant $C$ and some function $f$ belonging to [specified class].*  Your problem is the version  [specified class] = [continuous functions].  We could (and others have) ask for  [specified class] = [BV functions] or = [functions in $L_p[a,b]$] etc.  The goal is to find an intrinsic characterization.  Obviously one doesn't want merely that $F'$ is continuous.

Comment: I agree with your characterization. My question here is exactly what kind of instrinsic character would this function $F(x)$ have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an answer *but I do not want it upvoted* since it is not in the spirit of the question.  What we really want is some property expressed more directly in terms of the values of $F$ that is both necessary and sufficient in order that $F'$ exists and is continuous.  I offer this a "close but no cigar."

> **Theorem**. A necessary and sufficient condition that $F:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is continuously differentiable on $[a,b]$ is that $F$ has a
>   strong derivative at every point of that interval.

The strong derivative was introduced by Peano in 1892 (who called it a *strict derivative* and recommended that it should be used in elementary courses instead of the ordinary derivative).  Unfortunately the "strong" terminology sticks, although "strict" would have been better.  It is defined as
$$D^\sharp F(x) = \lim_{(u,v)\to (x,x)} \frac{F(v)-F(u)}{v-u}$$
and sometimes called an "unstraddled" derivative since the limit here is not computed only for intervals $[u,v]$ that contain or straddle  $x$, but for all "close" to $x$.

It has appeared before in a StackExchange [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85069/strong-derivative-of-a-monotone-function) where Dave Renfro supplies a (probably) complete bibliography on the topic.

An equivalent answer, but sufficiently disguised that it may appear profound, is to express this in terms of the Dini derivatives.

> **Theorem**. A necessary and sufficient condition that a continuous
>   function $F:[a,b]\to \mathbb R$ is continuously differentiable on
>   $[a,b]$ is that at every point of that interval   one at least of the
>   four Dini derivatives is continuous.

That is also not particularly intrinsic.
I do have an intrinsic answer in mind but it is not going to make the OP happy so maybe this weak answer suffices.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'm more than happy to hear your answer mind actually :)