# Weak tangent vs. Strong tangent

Tags: differential-geometry

Background: Given $\alpha : I \rightarrow R$, a simple curve of class $C^0$, do Carmo defines $\alpha$ to have a *weak tangent* at $t=t_0 \in I$ if the line determined by $\alpha (t_0 +h)$ and $\alpha (t_0)$ has a limit position when $h \rightarrow 0$. Also, he defines $\alpha$ to have a *strong tangent* at $t=t_0$ if the line determined by $\alpha (t_0 +h)$ and $\alpha (t_0 + k)$ has a limit position when $h,k \rightarrow 0$.

Question: What does it mean for a *line* to have a limit position exactly? Also, $\alpha (t) = (t^2, t^3)$ seems to be an example of a curve having a weak tangent but not a strong tangent. Do these definitions have relevance to the fact that $\alpha$ is not regular $\alpha '(t) = 0$ at point $t=0$?

Thanks!

Comment: Which book of him?

Comment: It's from the second edition of differential geometry of curves and surfaces

Comment: Well, without anything too fancy, a line in the plane has an equation $y=mx+b$ for some real numbers $m$ and $b$. If you have lines $L_t: y=m_tx+b_t$, they'll have a limit $y=mx+b$ precisely when $m_t\to m$ and $b_t\to b$. (We'll have to handle vertical lines separately, but you can figure that out.)

Comment: Yes, if the parametrization has non-vanishing derivative at $t=t_0$, then you'll get a strong tangent.

Comment: @Ted Shifrin Thanks. For the example of $\alpha (t) = (t^3,t^2)$, I took the slope of the line joining $\alpha(t_0)$ and $\alpha (t_0+h)$ to be $\frac{y(t_0 +h)-y(t_0)}{x(t_0 +h) - x(t_0)} = \frac{h^2}{h^3}$, which approaches infinity as $h \rightarrow 0$; but doesn't this mean the line would have no limit? But this particular curve should have a weak tangent, I'm not sure why.

Comment: Remember that I said you have to handle vertical lines separately. When you're going to have a vertical line as a limit, do $x=ky+c$ instead.

Comment: Do you mean that we must check $\frac{dx}{dy}$ also if $\frac{dy}{dx}$ does not converge to a limit as $h\rightarrow 0$? Wouldn't the former always converge if the latter diverges?

Comment: That last question was a bit vague. Of course, if $|\frac{dy}{dx}|\to\infty$, then $\frac{dx}{dy} \to 0$, but you can have other ways that $\frac{dy}{dx}$ fails to have a finite limit.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean. Thanks!

Comment: I believe this is strongly related --- pun intended --- to the notion of "strong derivative" I discuss in my answer to [“Strong” derivative of a monotone function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85069/strong-derivative-of-a-monotone-function/85086#85086). In particular, see pp. 104-105 in [**The Elementary Differential Geometry of Plane Curves**](https://archive.org/details/elementarydiffer00fowlrich) by Ralph Howard Fowler (1920). In early literature there was often no distinction made between tangents obtained as arbitrary approaching chord limits **(continued)**

Comment: and chord limits with one endpoint fixed. Fowler's book is the earliest non-specialist publication I know of which draws attention to this distinction.