# Monotone Function, Derivative Limit Bounded - Differentiable?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

Is there an example of a function $f \colon [a,b] \to \mathbb{R} $ that satisfies the following conditions:

1. $f$ is strictly monotone.
2. $\exists r>0 \colon \forall x \in [a,b], \forall h \in \mathbb{R} \colon |\frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}| < r $

which is not differentiable at some point in $[a,b]$?

Inspired by the non-differentiability of the Cantor function, where at each removed point there is a partial limit of the derivative definition, that goes to $\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Define$$\begin{array}{rccc}f\colon&[-1,1]&\longrightarrow&\mathbb R\\&x&\mapsto&\begin{cases}x&\text{ if }x<0\\2x&\text{otherwise.}\end{cases}\end{array}$$

Comment: will such a function have only a finite number of points of non-differentiability? Do they have to be isolated? Is it possible for them to be dense?

Comment: @co.sine Please post that as another question.

Comment: For pretty much any question I suspect co.sine could formulate, the answer is probably somewhere in my 3 November 2000 sci.math post [ESSAY ON NON-DIFFERENTIABILITY POINTS OF MONOTONE FUNCTIONS](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=274836). For a stronger notion of "finitely differentiable", see my answer to [“Strong” derivative of a monotone function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/85069/strong-derivative-of-a-monotone-function).

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos Posted as another question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746930/monotone-function-derivative-limit-bounded-differentiable-2?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro thank you, I'll have a look at your post. Will you also look at my question? -https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2746930/monotone-function-derivative-limit-bounded-differentiable-2?noredirect=1&lq=1